# Generate all 4-perfect numbers

Tags: code-golf, math, number, kolmogorov-complexity, number-theory

Your program or function should output all the [36 4-perfect numbers](http://oeis.org/A027687/b027687.txt) in increasing order  separated by newlines.

An `n` positive integer is a `k`-perfect number ([multiply perfect number](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Multiply_perfect_number)) if the sum of its divisors including itself (i.e. the [sigma function](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Divisor_function) of `n`) equals `k*n`.

For example `120` is a `3`-perfect number because `1 + 2 + 3 + 4 + 5 + 6 + 8 + 10 + 12 + 15 + 20 + 24 + 30 + 40 + 60 + 120 = 360 = 3*120`.

#### Details

- Your entry should actually produce the output and terminate on your machine before you submit your answer. (i.e. the program should terminate in a reasonable time)
- Hardcoding is allowed.
- Built-in functions or data closely related to the problem (e.g. sigma function) are disallowed.
- This is code-golf but as the task is non-trivial without major
  hardcoding non-golfed entries are welcomed too.

([This](http://wwwhomes.uni-bielefeld.de/achim/mpn.html) is a great detailed page about the history of all multiply perfect numbers.)

Comment: What counts as "partial" hardcoding?

Comment: "Your entry should actually produce the output on your machine not just in theory." In what time frame? Furthermore, what functions are closely related? Is `Divisors[n]` closely related? Is `Divisible[m,n]` closely related? Is `Mod[m,n]` closely related?

Comment: @MartinBüttner No time frame. Non of those are closely related. The purpose of that rule is to disallow simple one-liners available in some languages.
@Geobits Removed `partial`.

Comment: @MartinBüttner I don't know how else can I say that if you had seen the output appear on your screen than you can post the program because it actually produced the output not just theoretically.

Comment: For those of you trying to get started, here's some structure I noticed: The numbers tend to have many small prime factors, and the large prime factors are all one less than a product of smaller prime factors in the factorization. For example, the largest number `1598455815964665104598224777343146075218771968` is divisible by `2^37`, its largest prime factor `524287` is `2^19-1`, and its second-largest prime factor `174763 = 4*43691 - 1`, where `43691` is its third-largest prime factor.

Comment: Everyone answer by hardcore?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

## CJam, 377 bytes

All the characters are part of extended ASCII, so I'm counting this as a single byte per character

```
"Ò|+^ø¥©~öôxõÕÊïB.X}Ã+ç
âà©¥;ØÓé@ä¦qØH®üzGOwCàæ/Â$ªh#þ>üJNDÂTR{^ÌýÂ±OáÉÚ6ï®I?Çvqf³e1é^¶­[Y½5ãþ#_-__xF'IMØ*¬È6Vô+§mâ?µTJÉ9$·Ùöµ¨±Dac&¼'h,q÷ZwÎE^§Å{åÁûà\µ;óÛ¤{n'ÜGÐÓR!³¥èè>(~\"NbU*ötmù¦ªUe|Rñ¾!a9TYÇ&êë½ôâ··¨JÆ­#Ù&îCÎÍð4q<­ÌÏïj;Åd*òz(x    ?ßâ%d8Æ¬ÔUÎ=¶îÖÀ+mHH9â\"=PÊ±edèËU·  /þr<ÆGR;|úÀè¶¡õrì@öÆ"255bBbAa/N*
```

I'm sure Stack Exchange will have swallowed some of the characters, so you might want to copy the code [from this pastebin](http://pastebin.com/6zHXexdT).

[Test it here.](http://cjam.aditsu.net/)

This solution is purely hardcoded. It interprets the code points of the characters as the digits of a base-255 number, gets the base-11 digits of that, splits on the digit `10` and joins the resulting arrays by newlines.

Comment: The byte counter says 314 chars and 451 bytes.

Comment: @KSFT As I said in the answer, don't copy the code from my answer, because Stack Exchange strips unprintable characters. Use the link in my answer instead, which should show all 377 characters. Furthermore, that site counts bytes in UTF-8, but it's not necessary to encode the input in UTF-8 since all characters are in extended ASCII, so one only needs a single byte to encode each character.

Comment: I did look at the link. It gave the same numbers as copying the code from your answer. It said 314 chars both times.

Comment: @KSFT Hm, the link does work for me. Did you copy it in first, and *then* use the link? In some browsers, the permalinks don't work and are overridden by whatever you last opened in the counter.

Comment: Huh...that is weird... I typed something else in the counter, then opened the link in a new tab, and it had what I had typed instead of your code!

Comment: @KSFT Lesson learned, replaced it with a pastebin link.

Answer (score 5):

## Prime factorization (Ruby ,<s>570</s> 542 bytes)

**Rev 0**

Below is a table of the prime factorizations of the 36 required numbers (copied from Wolfram, hopefully with no errors.) Only 31 prime factors are involved if I have counted correctly, and some of these always occur together, for example 137*547*1093 and 683*2731*8191.

It should be possible to condense the information in the table, or perhaps even employ a search strategy. This should beat simply compressing the numbers.

Unfortunately the numbers are too big even for a 128-bit integer, which means I can't use C. Ruby and Python do support arbitrary precision integers. I have put the table in valid Ruby syntax, which makes it my first ever Ruby program!

```
puts 2**5  *3**3  *5    *7
puts 2**3  *3**2  *5    *7           *13
puts 2**2  *3**2  *5    *7**2        *13      *19
puts 2**9  *3**3  *5          *11                         *31   
puts 2**7  *3**3  *5**2                  *17              *31
puts 2**9  *3**2        *7    *11    *13                  *31
puts 2**8  *3     *5    *7                    *19             *37       *73
puts 2**10 *3**3  *5**2                               *23 *31                 *89
puts 2**13 *3**3  *5          *11                                 *43                 *127
puts 2**14 *3     *5    *7                    *19         *31                                   *151
puts 2**13 *3**2        *7    *11    *13                          *43                 *127
puts 2**5  *3**4        *7**2 *11**2          *19**2                                  *127
puts 2**8  *3**2        *7**2        *13      *19**2          *37       *73           *127
puts 2**7  *3**10 *5                     *17          *23                        *107                                               *3851   
puts 2**7  *3**6  *5                     *17          *23                                  *137           *547           *1093
puts 2**14 *3**2        *7**2        *13      *19**2      *31                         *127      *151
puts 2**5  *3**4        *7**2 *11**2          *19**4                                            *151                *911
puts 2**9  *3**4        *7    *11**3                      *31**2     *61    *83                      *331
puts 2**8  *3**2        *7**2        *13      *19**4            *37     *73                     *151                *911
puts 2**25 *3**3  *5**2                       *19         *31                                                  *683            *2731       *8191
puts 2**17 *3**10       *7                    *19**2  *23       *37     *73      *107 *127                                           *3851
puts 2**17 *3**6        *7                    *19**2  *23       *37     *73           *127 *137           *547           *1093
puts 2**25 *3**4        *7    *11**2          *19**2                                  *127                     *683            *2731       *8191
puts 2**25 *3**5        *7**2        *13      *19**2                                  *127                     *683            *2731       *8191
puts 2**17 *3**10       *7                    *19**4  *23       *37     *73      *107           *151                *911             *3851
puts 2**25 *3**10 *5                          *19     *23                        *107                          *683            *2731 *3851 *8191
puts 2**17 *3**6        *7                    *19**4  *23       *37     *73                *137 *151      *547      *911 *1093
puts 2**25 *3**6  *5                          *19     *23                                  *137           *547 *683      *1093 *2731       *8191
puts 2**25 *3**4        *7    *11**2          *19**4                                            *151           *683 *911       *2731       *8191
puts 2**25 *3**5        *7**2        *13      *19**4                                            *151           *683 *911       *2731       *8191
puts 2**33 *3**4        *7    *11**3                      *31        *61    *83                      *331                                        *43691 *131071
puts 2**33 *3**10       *7    *11                     *23                   *83  *107                *331                      *3851             *43691 *131071
puts 2**33 *3**6        *7    *11                     *23                   *83            *137      *331 *547           *1093                   *43691 *131071
puts 2**37 *3**4        *7    *11**3                      *31        *61    *83                      *331                                        *43691        *174763*524287
puts 2**37 *3**10       *7    *11                     *23                   *83  *107                *331                      *3851             *43691        *174763*524287
puts 2**37 *3**6        *7    *11                     *23                   *83            *137      *331 *547           *1093                   *43691        *174763*524287
```

**Rev 1**
Just starting to gather some terms.

```
#683*2731*8191=15278451143, 137*547*1093=81908327, 107*3851=412057, 174763*524287=91625968981, 19**2*151*911=49659521, 83*331=27473, 11**3*31*61=2516921,37*73=2701,19*19=361

puts 2**5  *3**3  *5       *7
puts 2**3  *3**2  *5       *7           *13
puts 2**2  *3**2  *5       *7**2        *13      *19
puts 2**9  *3**3  *5             *11                         *31    
puts 2**7  *3**3  *5**2                     *17              *31
puts 2**9  *3**2           *7    *11    *13                  *31
puts 2**8  *3     *5       *7                    *19                *2701
puts 2**10 *3**3  *5**2                                  *23 *31                 *89
puts 2**13 *3**3  *5             *11                                 *43                 *127
puts 2**14 *3     *5       *7                    *19         *31                               *151
puts 2**13 *3**2           *7    *11    *13                          *43                 *127
puts 2**5  *3**4           *7**2 *11**2          *19**2                                  *127
puts 2**8  *3**2           *7**2        *13      *19**2            *2701                 *127
puts 2**7  *3**10 *5                        *17          *23                                                                           *412057  
puts 2**7  *3**6  *5                        *17          *23                                                                *81908327
puts 2**14 *3**2           *7**2        *13      *19**2      *31                         *127  *151
puts 2**5  *3**4           *7**2 *11**2          *19**2                                            *49659521
puts 2**9  *3**4           *7                                *31    *2516921  *27473
puts 2**8  *3**2           *7**2        *13      *19**2            *2701                           *49659521
puts 2**25 *3**3  *5**2                          *19         *31                                                            *15278451143
puts 2**17 *3**10          *7                    *19**2  *23       *2701                 *127                                           *412057
puts 2**17 *3**6           *7                    *19**2  *23       *2701                 *127                               *81908327
puts 2**25 *3**4           *7    *11**2          *19**2                                  *127                                                   *15278451143
puts 2**25 *3**5           *7**2        *13      *19**2                                  *127                                                   *15278451143
puts 2**17 *3**10          *7                    *19**2  *23       *2701                           *49659521                            *412057
puts 2**25 *3**10 *5                             *19     *23                                                                            *412057 *15278451143
puts 2**17 *3**6           *7                    *19**2  *23       *2701                           *49659521                *81908327
puts 2**25 *3**6  *5                             *19     *23                                                                *81908327           *15278451143
puts 2**25 *3**4           *7    *11**2          *19**2                                            *49659521                                    *15278451143
puts 2**25 *3**5           *7**2        *13      *19**2                                            *49659521                                    *15278451143
puts 2**33 *3**4           *7                                       *2516921   *27473                                                               *43691 *131071
puts 2**33 *3**10          *7    *11                     *23                   *27473                                             *412057           *43691 *131071
puts 2**33 *3**6           *7    *11                     *23                   *27473                                       *81908327               *43691 *131071
puts 2**37 *3**4           *7                                       *2516921   *27473                                                               *43691        *91625968981
puts 2**37 *3**10          *7    *11                     *23                   *27473                                             *412057           *43691        *91625968981
puts 2**37 *3**6           *7    *11                     *23                   *27473                                       *81908327               *43691        *91625968981
```

**Rev 2, <s>570</s>  542 bytes (thanks to Martin for the improvement)**

As this is my first Ruby program, I just stuck with the simple approach of continuing to gather terms. Compression of the numbers would be great if anyone knows how to do that.

I could save a few more bytes by evaluating some of the literal-only expressions in the variable assignment part, but I decided to leave them for clarity.

```
e=361
f=e*e*137561
g=27473
h=2516921
j=2701
k=81908327*729
m=412057*59049
n=15278451143*2**25
p=g*43691*2**33*7
q=131071
r=91625968981*16
s=127
t=1024
w=250240
x=1467648
y=7439488
puts [30240,32760,2178540,23569920,45532800,142990848,510720*j,t*42833475,t*510840*s,t*149417520,t*3099096*s,15367968*e*s,x*e*j*s,w*m,w*k,t*429378768*e*s,15367968*f,8999424*g*h,x*j*f,n*397575,t*m*y*j*s,t*k*y*j*s,n*68607*e*s,n*154791*e*s,t*20608*j*f*m,2185*n*m,t*20608*j*f*k,2185*k*n,68607*f*n,154791*f*n,81*h*p*q,253*p*m*q,253*p*k*q,81*h*p*r,253*p*m*r,253*p*k*r]
```

Comment: no need for all that assignment to `z` and the for loop at the end. simply put the `puts` right in front of that array (and I don't think you'll need a space after the `puts` in that case). you should be able to save a few more bytes, by e.g. assigning `j` when it's first used, like `...,510720*j=2701,...`. and I think a few more if you give `253*p` a name.

Comment: Thanks @MartinBüttner, I had assumed that `puts [1,2,3]` would not insert a newline after each number, but it seems it does, at least in interactive mode on my PC (but not on the Ruby website.) I will edit that in later. I reckon with a bit of effort it should be possible to get close to 500 bytes with this type of program, but I'm not that interested in pushing it further right now. When I know more Ruby I'd like to use some kind of compression *as well as* taking advantage of the prime factorisation. Or you could post an answer and show me how it's done :-D

Comment: Ruby has a bit-shift operator `a<<b`, which lets you write `a*2**b` shorter.

Answer (score 3):

## JavaScript, 572 (?) bytes

```js
_=>`@r>=V6R=bWn3s*Ch=%{Fg>QNM'|c6SMH>wF=*
IElopM2Mw=?-,Knb7bW{\\=\rH3j=N9.3l*jm6Y(.wJP|
tFR7vmvt/))*D.F)  . n}Hk18KTn0a{E6
w1z0]\\o.jV"ytga25d+~VNP{0v:zq[d)  |.]d,t6P5:;:*?9m[8sI>\\R"'
wG*<#[^L/HFzAISvBDnmuy;+JNQj_n{[*d6DH#HtsLt}\`T+DX3T6/17
guv,\\d8G!\\9;Wug[78\\Iw]5"
r!~ZqN96Y\\99-gCoT_w.3SHF:p||;j*uwm+
1mSXJ<bE1UT]\r:(QEJ3LGPM$8Le3WXCoU;3*jW.7:"5m7f"0S3k9Eko`.replace(/./gs,p=>p.charCodeAt().toString(2).padStart(7,0).slice(-7)).replace(/00|01.|1...|111$/g,d=>`0 12   
3456789
`[parseInt(d,2)])
```

Potentially slightly more than 572, but without TIO I'm not sure if a different interpreter I used is counting a few `0x80` bytes (two bytes in UTF-8) correctly.

**Explanation:**

Uses huffman coding, where between two and four bits map to each digit:

```
0   00
1   010
2   011
3   1000
4   1001
5   1010
6   1011
7   1100
8   1101
9   1110
\n  1111 or 111
```

Each character is ASCII, so I get seven bits per byte. Some, like `` ` `` and `\` need two bytes, and `\0` (null) is represented with `0x80`.

Answer (score 3):

## [Scratch](https://scratch.mit.edu/), 327 bytes (Illegitimate)

[Try it online!](https://scratch.mit.edu/projects/514931746)

I was really excited to submit this answer, but then I read the first rule, stating that my program must generate all 36 numbers before I can submit. However, this rule makes hard-coding the only viable option, which is not optimal. I decided to circumvent the several millennia necessary to satisfy this rule, and submitted an answer anyway! To make up for this heinous act, I will be explaining the code in depth here, in addition to on Scratch.

### Full code

```
when gf clicked
delete all of[4 v
delete all of[f v
set[N v]to(
forever
change[N v]by(1
set[F v]to(
repeat until<(F)=(N
change[F v]by(1
repeat until<((N)/(F))=(round((N)/(F
change[F v]by(1
end
add(F)to[f v
end
set[S v]to(
repeat(length of[f v
set[S v]to((S)+(item(1)of[f v
delete(1)of[f v
end
if<(S)=((N)*(4))>then
add(N)to[4 v
```

### Setup

```
when gf clicked       Initiates the code
delete all of[4 v     Clears the list of 4-perfect numbers
delete all of[f v     Clears any residual factors from a previous run of the code
set[N v]to(           Sets the number that will be checked for 4-perfection to 0
forever               Run the following code an infinite amount of times
```

### Factorization

```
change[N v]by(1                       Increments the number to be tested for 4-perfection
set[F v]to(                           Resets the factor that will be tested on the number
repeat until<(F)=(N                   Runs the following code when there is still a factor to be checked for
change[F v]by(1                       Increments the factor that will be tested on the number
repeat until<((N)/(F))=(round((N)/(F  Loops code until a valid factor is found
change[F v]by(1                       Increments the factor that will be tested on the number
end                                   Marks the end of the code that needs to loop
add(F)to[f v                          Adds the valid factor to the list of factors
end                                   Marks the end of the code that needs to loop
```

### Summation

```
set[S v]to(                       Resets the sum of the factors
repeat(length of[f v              Loops code for each factor in the list
set[S v]to((S)+(item(1)of[f v     Adds item 1 of the factor list to itself
delete(1)of[f v                   Deletes the obsolete 1st item in the list, making the 2nd item the new 1st item
end                               Marks the end of the code that needs to loop
```

### 4-Perfection Check

```
if<(S)=((N)*(4))>then     Runs code if the sum of factors is 4 times the original value
add(N)to[4 v              Adds the 4-perfect value to the list
                   NB: "if", "repeat", and "forever", blocks don't need an "end" statement when they're at the end of a script.
                   NB: Groupings ([], (), <>) don't need to be closed if they're at the end of a line.
```

Please understand that I have no intentions of undermining the integrity of the challenge, but I wanted to demonstrate the potential of non hard-coded programs. Scratch is a moderately verbose language- imagine how small a more golf-friendly language could be!

Answer (score 2):

## Deadfish~, 3758 bytes

```
{iiiii}icdddciiciicddddc{dddd}iic{iiii}icdciiiiicdcddddddc{dddd}iic{iiii}cdciiiiiicicdddcdcddddc{dddd}iic{iiii}ciciiciciiicc{d}iiicddc{dddd}iic{iiii}iiciccddcdciiiiiic{d}iicc{dddd}iic{iiii}dciiicddc{i}dddcc{d}ic{i}ddcddddciiiic{dddd}ddddddc{iiii}dciiciiiiciicdddddcicdciiicdddddcddc{dddd}iic{iiii}iicdciiiiicddcdddddciiiciiicicddddcddddcc{dddd}iic{iiii}iiiiccddcdcciiiicdddddcddciiicdcddc{dddd}iic{iiii}dciiiicddcdddcciiiciicdcddddciiiiciiiic{d}iic{dddd}iic{iiii}iicddddciiicdddciiicddciciciiiccddddddc{i}ddc{dddd}ddddddc{iiii}iiiiic{d}iiiciiiiciciicddcdddcciiiiiiccicdddc{dddd}ddddc{iiii}dc{i}dddc{d}iiiciiiiiicdddcddciiiiiiccdddddciciiciiic{d}iciiiiicic{dddd}ddddc{iiii}iiiicddddddc{i}ddccdcdddddciiiiiic{d}iiciicdcciiiiicddddddciiicdcddc{dddd}iic{iiii}dciiiciiiiicdddddcddcdcicicdciiiiicdccddcdddc{i}ddc{d}iiicddc{dddd}iic{iiii}cddciciiiiciiic{d}iiic{i}dddcdddciiicdddciicddcddcddc{i}ddc{d}iciiiic{dddd}ddc{iiii}ciiiiicddccdddddciic{i}dddc{d}icciiiiiciiiicdddddcddddciicdciiicddddc{i}ddc{dddd}ddddddc{iiii}iiiicddddccciiiiiicddcdcdddddciiiiiiciic{d}iiicciiiicddddciiiicddciiiiiic{d}iiic{dddd}c{iiii}iiiiicddddddcdciiiiiicdcdddddc{i}dddcddcddddcdciiiicdddc{i}ddc{d}icc{i}dddcddddcdddc{i}ddcc{dddd}ddddddc{iiii}cddciiiciiiiicddddddcddc{i}dddc{d}iiiccc{i}ddcdddddciiicdddcicddciiicdciicddcdcdcddcc{dddd}iic{iiii}iiiicdddciiciiicdddddcdddciicddciciiiiicccddddddciic{i}dddcdddddcdcddc{i}ddcdcdcicicdddcdddcdc{dddd}c{iiii}dciiiicicddddddciiiciiicicdddciiiicicdddddcciiicddddciiiiiic{d}iciciiiiiicdddciciiiic{d}iicdciiiiiciiciic{d}iiic{dddd}c{iiii}dciiiiicdddddciciiicddcdciiiiiicddcddddddcc{i}dcddciicddddddcdciiiiciicddddddciciiiiicddcicddddciicddddcdciiiic{dddd}ddc{iiii}iciiicdddciiiiic{d}iiic{i}ddcddddddciiiiiicddcddddciiicddddddc{i}dcddddddciiiiicdddcddcdddc{i}ddc{d}iiic{i}ddcdddddciiiicddcdcddddciiiicdddc{dddd}c{iiii}ciiciiiicddcddddcccicdddciiiccddciciiciiicdddcddc{i}dddcdddcddcdddcccdciiicdddc{i}dddcdddciiicddddddciiciiic{dddd}ddddc{iiii}ciiiiicdddddciiiccdddciiiiicddddddcdc{i}dcdccicdddddcdciiicicdcicddddcciiiiicicddddcdddddcciiiccicddddc{i}ddc{d}iic{dddd}iic{iiii}iiiicdddddcdciciiciciiccddddcciiiiiicddddddc{i}dddc{d}iicic{i}dddccdc{d}iiic{i}ddc{d}iiciicdciiicdddciiicddciciiciic{d}iiiciiiiic{dddd}ddddc{iiii}iiiicciiccddcdddddciiiiciicddddciiiiicdddcdddddciiicdddciiiiiicddcddddcciiiciiiiiic{d}iicdc{i}dcddddddcdddc{i}dddciic{d}iiiciicciiiic{d}iic{dddd}iic{iiii}iiiicdddcdddciiiiicddcdciciiciiccddddddcdciiiicddcddcc{i}dddciicddddcdddddc{i}ddcddddcddciiiiiicdddddciiicddddciciicdddddciiiiiciiiic{d}iiic{dddd}c{iiii}dciiicddcciiiicddddddciiiiiicddddddciiiiiicdddcdciiiicddcddddcciiiiicicdddcciiiiiicddddddcdcciciiiiiic{d}iic{i}ddcddcc{d}iiiccc{i}dcdddc{dddd}ddddc{iiii}dc{i}ddc{d}iiiciiiiiicddcddddccicdddcciiciciiicdddcddc{i}dddc{d}iiciiiiciiiiicc{d}iiiciiiiiicddddddciiiciiic{d}iiiciiccddciiiiicddcddddciiicdc{dddd}c{iiii}iiiciiicddddddciciciiiicddddciiiciic{d}iicciiiiciiicdddciicdddcdciiicdddciiiiiic{d}iic{i}ddc{d}iicciiiicdddddciiciiiciiicdciic{d}iic{i}ddc{d}ic{i}dddcddddcdciiiiiic{dddd}ddddddc{iiii}dciiicddc{i}dddc{d}iicc{i}ddccdddcdddcdddc{i}dcddciicdddddciiicddddcciiiiciicdddcdddcdc{i}dddc{d}iiic{i}dddc{d}ic{i}dcddciicdddddciiciic{d}iiicciiiiciiiicdddciic{dddd}ddddddc{iiii}cdciiiiciicddddddciiicdciiiiiicdcdddcdddciiiicddddddcicciiciiiiiicdddddcddciiiicic{d}iiic{i}dddciic{d}iciiiiicdddddciiiiiciicdddddcdciiiiicdddddciiicddciiicdddddc{i}ddc{d}iiciiicdc{dddd}c{iiii}iiiicdcddddciiciicdddddc{i}dddcddddddciiiiiicddcdddddciiciicciiiccddddciiiiiic{d}iiiciiiiiic{d}iiicdcicicdciiicddddciicicicccdddcciiiiiicddddddciiciiiiciicdddciicdddddccdciiiiiic{dddd}ddddddc{iiii}dciiiiciiiicdcddddcicciiic{d}iiiciiiiciiiicdddcddciiccdcddddcdciiiiciciiiicdcddddddcciiciiicccddddcicdcddciiiciicddddddc{i}dddcddcdddcdc{i}dddcdccddddddc{i}ddcdddciic
```

It had to be done.

Comment: Do you use any kind of generators for generating such huge Deadfish~ codes?

Answer (score 1):

## Perl, 629 bytes

(Not counting one line break added for legibility)

```
use bignum;$_="762K7FF8G213DECG167A6O2B6C68K885DEO5238CFOA36590COF77C22S239FB8CS5DD688ASA40BF4CBEKA54B500277O15A1AA76D5D18K3515C82E18268K479DC3635ACS3D2C86DAC7F142K8A2CE47EB04E2O3DA39DD49D1B489O2B29246D35B6E2_34983A6E0D56A03116W8112111C1388B007CAW535DB1D8191384C3E_BC1718A816B9CA38E_139CE2CE0C2A6520D7D64EAW1580287D7C721FC8E0EFE_30219245E63381BDAD34236W34C38D4A316E11A76BA62_1F166FEDE2AA3B8DEE71C2_4623D01AD5164B207D6A72_5F16A2BFB16257500DB6g2BCF9FAD6C4DE65CA22F8C6Eg6B83D96C6A0809DCDEC5BFF2g3F648C3210B25B8737B940492k1D3523B8D99B8761B6AFBE903D97Ak47AD5F744AA0CC4A843901F8DEAA6k";
s#(\w+?)([G-z])#print hex($1)<<(ord($2)-71),$/#ge
```

The numbers are hard-coded in hexadecimal with a bit of compression applied to the trailing zeroes.

[Try it out here.](http://ideone.com/94tEJY)