# Calculate the first n perfect numbers

Tags: code-golf, math

Write a program that calculates the first n perfect numbers. A perfect number is one where the sum of the factors is the original number. For example, 6 is a perfect number because 1+2+3=6. No non standard libraries.The standard loopholes are forbidden.

Comment: Please clarify: What is a non-standard library? Also, how should output be given?

Comment: [Related.](http://codegolf.stackexchange.com/q/44814/8478)

Answer (score 2):

## Pyth - <strike>27</strike> 25 bytes

Extremely super slow brute force approach.

```
K2W<ZQ~K1IqKsf!%KTr1KK~Z1
```

Trial division to factor, then while loop till length of perfect numbers is enough.

[Try it here online](http://pyth.herokuapp.com/?code=K2W%3CZQ%7EK1IqKsf!%25KTr1KK%7EZ1&input=3).

Comment: Does prime factorization using `P` speed anything up?

Comment: @orlp possibly, but we want all factors, not primes.

Comment: I'm aware, but you can compute the sigma function from the factorization.

Answer (score 2):

## Pyth, 25 bytes

```
J1W<lYQy=JI!tPKtyJaY*JK;Y
```

Tests whether Mersenne numbers are prime. If so, it generates the corresponding perfect number. Can find the first 8 perfect numbers in under a second.

Note: Only generates even perfect numbers. However, since it has been proven that [any odd perfect number is greater than 10^1500](http://www.lirmm.fr/~ochem/opn/opn.pdf), this algorithm is correct on inputs up to 14.

[Demonstration.](https://pyth.herokuapp.com/?code=J1W%3ClYQy%3DJI!tPKtyJaY*JK%3BY&input=8&debug=0)

Comment: This answer will skip odd perfect numbers.

Answer (score 2):

## CJam, 24 bytes

```
1{{2*_(mp!}g__(*2/p}ri*;
```

[Try it online.](http://cjam.aditsu.net/#code=1%7B%7B2*_(mp!%7Dg__(*2%2Fp%7Dri*%3B&input=8)

Makes use of the [Euclid–Euler theorem](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Euclid%E2%80%93Euler_theorem):

An even number `P` is perfect iff `P = 2 ** (N - 1) * (2 ** N - 1)` where `2 ** N - 1` is prime.

#### Disclaimer

If there are odd perfect numbers, this code will fail to generate them. However, there are no known odd perfect numbers.

#### How it works

```
1                        e# A := 1
 {                 }ri*  e# do int(input()) times: 
  {       }g             e#   do:
   2*                    e#     A *= 2
     _(                  e#     M := A - 1
       mp!               e#   while(prime(P))
            __(2/        e#   P := A * (A - 1) / 2
                 p       e#   print(P)
                       ; e# discard(A)
```