# Am I perfect (number)?

Tags: code-golf, number-theory

This is my first challenge!

#### Background

[Perfect number](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Perfect_number) is a positive integer, that is equal to the sum of all its divisors, except itself.
So `6` is perfect number, since `1 + 2 + 3 = 6`.
On the other hand `12` is not, because `1 + 2 + 3 + 4 + 6 = 16 != 12`.

#### Task

Your task is simple, write a program, which will, for given `n`, print one of these messages:

> I am a perfect number, because `d1 + d2 + ... + dm = s == n`
>   I am not a perfect number, because `d1 + d2 + ... + dm = s [<>] n`

Where
`d1, ... dm` are all divisors of `n` except for `n`.
`s` is the sum of all divisors `d1, ..., dm` (again, without `n`).
`[<>]` is either `<` (if `s < n`) or `>` (if `s > n`).

#### Examples

For `n` being `6`: "I am a perfect number, because 1 + 2 + 3 = 6 == 6"
For `n` being `12`: "I am not a perfect number, because 1 + 2 + 3 + 4 + 6 = 16 > 12"
For `n` being `13`: "I am not a perfect number, because 1 = 1 < 13"

#### Rules

- `n` is not bigger than your language's standard `int`.
- You can read `n` from standard input, from command line arguments or from a file.
- Output message has to be printed on standard output and no additional characters can appear in the output (it may have trailing whitespace or newline)
- You may not use any built-ins or library functions which would solve the task (or its main part) for you. No `GetDivisors()` or something like that.
- All other [standard loopholes](http://meta.codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/1061/loopholes-that-are-forbidden-by-default) apply.

#### Winner

This is [code-golf](/questions/tagged/code-golf) so shortest code in **bytes** wins!

Comment: @orlp It is not, I edited the challenge, thanks for that.

Comment: Why do you use `=` and `==` in the same equation? That makes no sense. It should be `d1 + d2 + ... + dm = s = n` IMO.

Comment: Could you give some example input and output, for example with inputs 6 and 12?

Comment: @orlp first `=` is assignment. Second `==` is comparism.

Comment: @Zereges That's nonsensical. There is nothing being assigned. Only compared.

Comment: @orlp It is intended.

Comment: Related: http://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/49718/calculate-the-first-n-perfect-numbers

Comment: @flawr Related, but closed as unclear.

Comment: What is being assigned? I don't see any variables. I only see constants, and you can't assign anything to a constant.

Comment: @corsiKa Ok, so I'll tell it in other way. First `=` is elementary school's, it means, computing the value of sum of divisors. The second `==` is to show off, that the value is the same.

Comment: Does it matter if there are extra spaces in the list of numbers, e.g. ```I am a perfect number, because<space><space>1<space>+<space><space>2 +<space><space>4<space>+<space><space>7<space>+<space>14 == 28```

Comment: @TomCarpenter Yes, it matters. You can have trailing whitespace/newline, but no whitespaces in the middle of output.

Comment: I figured as much. Fortunately I found a way to combat it in my MATLAB code after I left the comment. :)

Comment: I wrote a four byte answer... and then I realized how the output is supposed to work.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

## Pyth, 81 bytes

```
jd[+WK-QsJf!%QTStQ"I am"" not""a perfect number, because"j" + "J\=sJ@c3"==<>"._KQ
```

Try it online: [Demonstration](http://pyth.herokuapp.com/?code=jd[%2BWK-QsJf!%25QTStQ%22I%20am%22%22%20not%22%22a%20perfect%20number%2C%20because%22j%22%20%2B%20%22J%5C%3DsJ%40c3%22%3D%3D%3C%3E%22._KQ&input=6&test_suite_input=24%0A26%0A28&debug=0) or [Test Suite](http://pyth.herokuapp.com/?code=jd[%2BWK-QsJf!%25QTStQ%22I%20am%22%22%20not%22%22a%20perfect%20number%2C%20because%22j%22%20%2B%20%22J%5C%3DsJ%40c3%22%3D%3D%3C%3E%22._KQ&input=6&test_suite=1&test_suite_input=24%0A26%0A28&debug=0)

#### Explanation:

```
                                 implicit: Q = input number
               StQ               the range of numbers [1, 2, ..., Q-1]
          f                      filter for numbers T, which satisfy:
           !%QT                     Q mod T != 0
         J                       save this list of divisors in J
      -QsJ                       difference between Q and sum of J
     K                           save the difference in K

jd[                              put all of the following items in a list
                                 and print them joined by spaces: 
                  "I am"           * "I am"
   +WK                  " not"       + "not" if K != 0
"a perfect number, because"        * "a perfect ..."
j" + "J                            * the divisors J joined by " + "
       \=                          * "="
         sJ                        * sum of J
            c3"==<>"               * split the string "==<>" in 3 pieces:
                                        ["==", "<", ">"]
           @        ._K              and take the (sign of K)th one (modulo 3)
                       Q           * Q
```

Answer (score 9):

## Java, <s>255</s> 270 bytes (Still FF in base 17)

```java
class C{public static void main(String[]a){int i=new Integer(a[0]),k=0,l=0;a[0]=" ";for(;++k<i;)if(i%k<1){l+=k;a[0]+=k+" ";}}System.out.print("I am "+(l==i?"":"not ")+"a perfect number, because "+a[0].trim().replace(" "," + ")+" = "+l+(l==i?" == ":l<i?" < ":" > ")+i);}}
```

And a more readable version:

```java
class C {
    public static void main(String[] a) {
        int i = new Integer(a[0]), k = 0, l = 0;
        a[0] = " ";
        for(; ++k<i ;){
            if (i % k == 0) {
                l += k;
                a[0] += k + " ";
            }
        }
        System.out.print("I am " + (l == i ? "" : "not ") + "a perfect number, because " + a[0].trim().replace(" "," + ") + " = " + l + (l == i ? " == " : l < i ? " < " : " > ") + i);
    }
}
```

Previously didn't work for odd numbers, so I had to tweak a few things. At least I got lucky with the byte count again. :)

Comment: will l == i work over 255 ?

Comment: I know if ruins your byte count, but you could save a character by replacing the last three (of four) occurrences of a[0] with a 'String b' and use 'b' in their place

Answer (score 6):

## R, <s>158</s> <s>163</s> <s>157</s> <s>153</s> <s>143</s> 141 bytes

Still room to golf this I think.
**Edit:** Replaced `if(b<n)'<'else if(b>n)'>'else'=='` with `c('<'[b<n],'>'[b>n],'=='[b==n])`.  The `paste(...)` is replaced with an `rbind(...)[-1]`.  Thanks @plannapus for a couple more bytes.

```R
n=scan();a=2:n-1;b=sum(w<-a[!n%%a]);cat('I am','not'[b!=n],'a perfect number, because',rbind('+',w)[-1],'=',b,c('<'[b<n],'>'[b>n],'==')[1],n)
```

Ungolfed

```R
n<-scan()             # get number from stdin
w<-which(!n%%1:(n-1)) # build vector of divisors
b=sum(w)              # sum divisors
cat('I am',           # output to STDOUT with a space separator
    'not'[b!=n],      # include not if b!=n
    'a perfect number, because',
    rbind('+',w)[-1], # create a matrix with the top row as '+', remove the first element of the vector
    '=',
    b,                # the summed value
    c(                # creates a vector that contains only the required symbol and ==
        '<'[b<n],     # include < if b<n
        '>'[b>n],     # include > if b>n
        '=='
    )[1],             # take the first element 
    n                 # the original number
)
```

Test run

```R
> n=scan();b=sum(w<-which(!n%%1:(n-1)));cat('I am','not'[b!=n],'a perfect number, because',rbind('+',w)[-1],'=',b,c('<'[b<n],'>'[b>n],'==')[1],n)
1: 6
2: 
Read 1 item
I am a perfect number, because 1 + 2 + 3 = 6 == 6
> n=scan();b=sum(w<-which(!n%%1:(n-1)));cat('I am','not'[b!=n],'a perfect number, because',rbind('+',w)[-1],'=',b,c('<'[b<n],'>'[b>n],'==')[1],n)
1: 12
2: 
Read 1 item
I am not a perfect number, because 1 + 2 + 3 + 4 + 6 = 16 > 12
> n=scan();b=sum(w<-which(!n%%1:(n-1)));cat('I am','not'[b!=n],'a perfect number, because',rbind('+',w)[-1],'=',b,c('<'[b<n],'>'[b>n],'==')[1],n)
1: 13
2: 
Read 1 item
I am not a perfect number, because 1 = 1 < 13
>
```

Comment: There should be `+` sign in between divisors.

Comment: @Zereges I've just noticed that and will fix shortly

Comment: +1 for the brilliant `rbind` trick! You can save 2 extra bytes if you assign `2:n-1` to a variable, say `a`: `which(!n%%1:(n-1))`  thus becomes `a[!n%%a]`. (The full code being then `n=scan();a=2:n-1;b=sum(w<-a[!n%%a]);cat('I am','not'[b!=n],'a perfect number, because',rbind('+',w)[-1],'=',b,c('<'[b<n],'>'[b>n],'==')[1],n)`)

Comment: @plannapus  Thanks, I was really pleased with that myself.

Answer (score 5):

## Python 2, <s>183</s> <s>173</s> 170 bytes

```python
b=input();c=[i for i in range(1,b)if b%i<1];d=sum(c);print'I am %sa perfect number because %s = %d %s %d'%('not '*(d!=b),' + '.join(map(str,c)),d,'=<>='[cmp(b,d)%3::3],b)
```

Examples:

```python
$ python perfect_number.py <<< 6
I am a perfect number because 1 + 2 + 3 = 6 == 6
$ python perfect_number.py <<< 12
I am not a perfect number because 1 + 2 + 3 + 4 + 6 = 16 > 12
$ python perfect_number.py <<< 13
I am not a perfect number because 1 = 1 < 13
$ python perfect_number.py <<< 100
I am not a perfect number because 1 + 2 + 4 + 5 + 10 + 20 + 25 + 50 = 117 > 100
$ python perfect_number.py <<< 8128
I am a perfect number because 1 + 2 + 4 + 8 + 16 + 32 + 64 + 127 + 254 + 508 + 1016 + 2032 + 4064 = 8128 == 8128
```

Thanks to [xnor](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/users/20260/xnor) for saving 13 bytes!

Comment: `'=<>'[cmp(b,d)]` - join the revolution!

Comment: Excellent, thanks! Oh, wait ... :)

Comment: @Celeo I came up with a similar solution. You can write `b%i<1` for `b%i==0`. For `['not ',''][int(d==b)]`, you don't need the `int`, because Python will convert automatically. Moreover, you can use string mulitplication `"not "*(d!=b)`.

Comment: @xnor thanks for the suggestions!

Comment: @Celeo You can adjust orlp's suggestion to work as `"=<>="[cmp(b,d)%3::3]`.

Comment: Clever, @xnor, thanks!

Answer (score 4):

## Julia, <s>161</s> 157 bytes

```julia
n=int(ARGS[1])
d=filter(i->n%i<1,1:n-1)
s=sum(d)
print("I am ",s!=n?"not ":"","a perfect number, because ",join(d," + ")," = $s ",s<n?"<":s>n?">":"=="," $n")
```

Ungolfed:

```julia
# Read n as the first command line argument
n = int(ARGS[1])

# Get the divisors of n and their sum
d = filter(i -> n % i == 0, 1:n-1)
s = sum(d)

# Print to STDOUT
print("I am ",
      s != n ? "not " : "",
      "a perfect number, because ",
      join(d, " + "),
      " = $s ",
      s < n ? "<" : s > n ? ">" : "==",
      " $n")
```

Answer (score 4):

## CJam, 90 bytes

```
"I am"rd:R{R\%!},:D:+R-g:Cz" not"*" a perfect number, because "D'+*'=+D:++'=C+_'=a&+a+R+S*
```

For comparison, printing a single `=` could be achieved in 83 bytes.

Try it online in the [CJam interpreter](http://cjam.aditsu.net/#code=%22I%20am%22rd%3AR%7BR%5C%25!%7D%2C%3AD%3A%2BR-g%3ACz%22%20not%22*%22%20a%20perfect%20number%2C%20because%20%22D'%2B*'%3D%2BD%3A%2B%2B'%3DC%2B_'%3Da%26%2Ba%2BR%2BS*&input=6).

#### How it works

```
"I am"  e# Push that string.
rd:R    e# Read a Double from STDIN and save it in R.
{       e# Filter; for each I in [0 ... R-1]:
  R\%!  e# Push the logical NOT of (R % I).
},      e# Keep the elements such that R % I == 0.
:D      e# Save the array of divisors in D.
:+R-g   e# Add the divisors, subtract R and compute the sign of the difference.
:Cz     e# Save the sign in C and apply absolute value.
"not "* e# Repeat the string "not " that many times.

" a perfect number, because "

D'+*    e# Join the divisors, separating by plus signs.
'=+D:++ e# Append a '=' and the sum of the divisors.
'=C+    e# Add the sign to '=', pushing '<', '=' or '>'.
_'=a&   e# Intersect a copy with ['='].
+a+     e# Concatenate, wrap in array and concatenate.
        e# This appends "<", "==" or ">".
R+      e# Append the input number.
S*      e# Join, separating by spaces.
```

Answer (score 2):

## Lua, <s>244</s> 231 bytes

Golfed:

```lua
n=io.read("*n")d={}s="1"t=1 for i=2,n-1 do if n%i==0 then table.insert(d,i)s=s.." + "..i t=t+i end end print(("I am%s a perfect number, because %s = %s"):format(t==n and""or" not", s, t..(t==n and" == "or(t>n and" > "or" < "))..n))
```

Ungolfed:

```lua
n=io.read("*n")
divisors={}
sequence="1"
sum=1
for i=2,n-1 do
    if n%i==0 then 
        table.insert(divisors,i)
        sequence=sequence.." + "..i
        sum=sum+i
    end
end

print(("I am%s a perfect number, because %s = %s"):format(sum==n and""or" not", sequence, sum..(sum==n and" == "or(sum>n and" > "or" < "))..n))
```

Answer (score 2):

## Perl, 148 Bytes

```perl
$a=<>;$_=join' + ',grep{$a%$_==0}1..$a-1;$s=eval;print"I am ".($s==$a?'':'not ')."a perfect number because $_ = $s ".(('==','>','<')[$s<=>$a])." $a"
```

With line breaks:

```perl
$a=<>;
$_=join' + ',grep{$a%$_==0}1..$a-1;
$s=eval;
print"I am ".($s==$a?'':'not ')."a perfect number because $_ = $s ".(('==','>','<')[$s<=>$a])." $a"
```

Comment: I've had a poke over this and you can save 10 bytes by removing the outer parens around the `'not '` and `'==','>','<'` statements and switching from `.` to `,` (since nothing is added when `print`ing a list). Also moving your assignments into parens the first time they're used saves a couple, and if you change the logic slightly to `grep$a%_<1,1..($a=<>)-1` and `$a!=($s=eval)&&'not '` you should shave off a few more! Hope that all makes sense!

Answer (score 2):

### Ruby, <s>174</s> <s>160</s> <s>155</s> <s>136</s> <s>134</s> <s>128</s> 122 Bytes

```
n=6;a=[*1...n].reject{|t|n%t>0};b=a.inject(:+)<=>n;print"I am#{" not"*b.abs} a perfect number, because ",a*?+,"<=>"[b+1],n
```

Saved another 6 Bytes :)

Thanks to
[Tips for golfing in Ruby](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/363/tips-for-golfing-in-ruby)

Comment: The print command still bothers me.. And I need to figure out a way to shorten the if-statement ternary ? needs an else clause I cannot provide and only accepts one call per case

Comment: only one print statement is left :)

Answer (score 2):

## JavaScript (ES6), 146

Using template strings, it works in Firefox and latest Chrome.

```js
for(n=prompt(),o=t=i=1;++i<n;)n%i||(t+=i,o+=' + '+i)
alert(`I am ${t-n?'not ':''}a perfect number because ${o} = ${t} ${t<n?'<':t>n?'>':'=='} `+n)
```

Answer (score 1):

## C#, 252 bytes

```c#
class A{static void Main(string[]a){int i=int.Parse(a[0]);var j=Enumerable.Range(1,i-1).Where(o=>i%o==0);int k=j.Sum();Console.Write("I am "+(i!=k?"not ":"")+"a perfect number, because "+string.Join(" + ",j)+" = "+k+(k>i?" > ":k<i?" < ":" == ")+i);}}
```

Answer (score 1):

## [Hassium](https://github.com/HassiumTeam/Hassium), 285 Bytes

Disclaimer: Works with only the latest version of Hassium due to issues with command line args.

```
func main(){n=Convert.toNumber(args[0]);s=1;l="1";foreach(x in range(2,n-3)){if(n%x==0){l+=" + "+x;s+=x;}}if(s==n)println("I am a perfect number, because "+l+" = "+s+" == "+s);else {print("I am not a perfect number, because "+l+" = "+s);if(s>n)println(" > "+n);else println(" < "+n);}}
```

More readable version:

```
func main() {
    n = Convert.toNumber(args[0]);
    s = 1;
    l = "1";
    foreach(x in range(2, n - 3)) {
            if (n % x== 0) {
                    l += " + " + x;
                    s += x;
            }
    }
    if (s == n)
            println("I am a perfect number, because " + l + " = " + s + " == " + s);
    else {
            print("I am not a perfect number, because " + l + " = " + s);
            if (s > n)
                    println(" > " + n);
            else
                    println(" < " + n);
    }
}
```

Comment: 1. I can't seem to convince Hassium to read my command-line arguments. If I execute `mono src/Hassium/bin/Debug/Hassium.exe t.hs 6`, it says `System.ArgumentException: The file 6 does not exist.`. 2. This doesn't work with [this version](https://github.com/HassiumTeam/Hassium/tree/555820304a51e15f487512ac5be1f87e303993fd), which is the lastest commit before this challenge was posted. Please add a disclaimer to your answer that state that your submission is non-competing.

Comment: I tried it on Windows (built using MVS2015) and got same error.

Comment: This is an issue that was updated literally 15 minutes ago. Clone the Hassium and compile again. I am very sorry as I ran into the exact same problem.

Comment: It works fine with the latest version. Now if you could just add the disclaimer, I'll be happy to remove my downvote. (By the way, you can ping me by adding `@Dennis` to your comment. Otherwise, I don't get notified of your reply.)

Comment: @Dennis I added it in. Thank you for your notification :)

Answer (score 1):

## MATLAB, 238

Never going to be the shortest of all languages, but here's my attempt with MATLAB:

```
n=input('');x=1:n-1;f=x(~rem(n,x));s=sum(f);a='not ';b=strjoin(strtrim(cellstr(num2str(f')))',' + ');if(s>n) c=' > ';elseif(s<n) c=' < ';else c=' == ';a='';end;disp(['I am ' a 'a perfect number, because ' b ' = ' num2str(s) c num2str(n)])
```

And this is in a slightly more readable form:

```
n=input();      %Read in the number using the input() function
x=1:n-1;        %All integers from 1 to n-1
f=x(~rem(n,x)); %Determine which of those numbers are divisors
s=sum(f);       %Sum all the divisors
a='not ';       %We start by assuming it is not perfect (to save some bytes)
b=strjoin(strtrim(cellstr(num2str(f')))',' + '); %Also convert the list of divisors into a string 
                                                 %where they are all separated by ' + ' signs.
%Next check if the number is >, < or == to the sum of its divisors
if(s>n)  
    c=' > ';    %If greater than, we add a ' > ' to the output string
elseif(s<n) 
    c=' < ';    %If less than, we add a ' < ' to the output string
else
    c=' == ';   %If equal, we add a ' == ' to the output string
    a='';       %If it is equal, then it is a perfect number, so clear the 'not' string
end

%Finally concatenate the output string and display the result
disp(['I am ' a 'a perfect number, because ' b ' = ' num2str(s) c num2str(n)])
```

I've managed to save 2 more bytes by not using a function. Instead you run the line of code and it requests the number as an input. Once run it displays the output at the end.

Answer (score 1):

### [Perl 6](http://perl6.org), 138 bytes

```perl6
$_=get;
my$c=$_ <=>my$s=[+] my@d=grep $_%%*,^$_;
say "I am {
    'not 'x?$c
  }a perfect number, because {
    join ' + ',@d
  } = $s {
    «> == <»[1+$c]
  } $_"
```

( The count ignores the newlines, and indents, because they aren't needed )

`@d` is the array holding the divisors.
`$s` holds the sum of the divisors.
`$c` is the value of the comparison between the input, and the sum of the divisors.
( effectively `$c` is one of `-1`,`0`,`1`, but is really one of `Order::Less`, `Order::Same`, or `Order::More` )

In `'not 'x?$c`, `?$c` in this case is effectively the same as `abs $c`, and `x` is the string repetition operator.

`«> == <»` is short for `( '>', '==', '<' )`.
Since `$c` has one of `-1,0,1`, we have to shift it up by one to be able to use it to index into a list.

Technically this will work for numbers well above 2⁶⁴, but takes an inordinate amount of time for numbers above 2¹⁶.

Answer (score 0):

## Pyth, 84 bytes

```
jd+,+"I am"*.aK._-QsJf!%QTtUQ" not""a perfect number, because"+.iJm\+tJ[\=sJ@"=<>"KQ
```

Invalid answer, because I refuse to implement `=` and `==` in the same equation.

Comment: +1 for refusing to "implement = and == in the same equation."

Answer (score 0):

## Ruby, 164 Bytes

```
->i{t=(1...i).select{|j|i%j==0};s=t.inject &:+;r=['==','>','<'][s<=>i];puts "I am #{'not ' if r!='=='}a perfect number, because #{t.join(' + ')} = #{s} #{r} #{i}"}
```

## Test

```
irb(main):185:0> ->i{t=(1...i).select{|j|i%j==0};s=t.inject &:+;r=['==','>','<'][s<=>i];puts "I am #{'not ' if r!='=='}a perfect number, because #{t.join(' + ')} = #{s} #{r} #{i}"}.call 6
I am a perfect number, because 1 + 2 + 3 = 6 == 6

irb(main):186:0> ->i{t=(1...i).select{|j|i%j==0};s=t.inject &:+;r=['==','>','<'][s<=>i];puts "I am #{'not ' if r!='=='}a perfect number, because #{t.join(' + ')} = #{s} #{r} #{i}"}.call 12
I am not a perfect number, because 1 + 2 + 3 + 4 + 6 = 16 > 12

irb(main):187:0> ->i{t=(1...i).select{|j|i%j==0};s=t.inject &:+;r=['==','>','<'][s<=>i];puts "I am #{'not ' if r!='=='}a perfect number, because #{t.join(' + ')} = #{s} #{r} #{i}"}.call 13
I am not a perfect number, because 1 = 1 < 13
```

Answer (score 0):

## Emacs Lisp, 302 Bytes

```
(defun p(n)(let((l(remove-if-not'(lambda(x)(=(% n x)0))(number-sequence 1(- n 1)))))(setf s(apply'+ l))(format"I am%s a perfect number, because %s%s = %s %s %s"(if(= s n)""" not")(car l)(apply#'concat(mapcar'(lambda(x)(concat" + "(number-to-string x)))(cdr l)))s(if(= sum n)"=="(if(> sum n)">""<"))n)))
```

Ungolfed version:

```
(defun perfect (n)
  (let ((l (remove-if-not '(lambda (x) (= (% n x) 0))
              (number-sequence 1 (- n 1)))))
    (setf sum (apply '+ l))
    (format "I am%s a perfect number, because %s%s = %s %s %s" (if (= sum n)"" " not") (car l)
        (apply #'concat (mapcar '(lambda (x) (concat " + " (number-to-string x))) (cdr l)))
        sum (if(= sum n)
            "=="
          (if(> sum n)
              ">"
            "<"))
        n)))
```

Answer (score 0):

## Powershell, 164 bytes

```
$a=$args[0]
$b=(1..($a-1)|?{!($a%$_)})-join" + "
$c=iex $b
$d=$a.compareto($c)
"I am $("not "*!!$d)a perfect number, because $b = $c $(("==","<",">")[$d]) $a"
```

A few of the common and not so common PoSh tricks;

- Create the sum, then evaluate it with iex
- Compareto to index the gt, lt, eq array
- !!$d will evaluate to true == 1 for $d = 1 or -1, and false == 0 for $d = 0

Answer (score 0):

## awk, 150

```
n=$0{for(p=i=s=n>1;++i<n;)for(;n%i<1;p+=i++)s=s" + "i;printf"I am%s a perfect number, because "s" = "p" %s "n RS,(k=p==n)?_:" not",k?"==":p<n?"<":">"}
```

Wasted some bytes on making this correct for input `1`. I'm not sure if that is expected.

```
n=$0{
    for(p=i=s=n>1;++i<n;)
        for(;n%i<1;p+=i++)s=s" + "i;
    printf "I am%s a perfect number, because "s" = "p" %s "n RS,
           (k=p==n)?_:" not",k?"==":p<n?"<":">"
}
```

Answer (score 0):

## [05AB1E](https://github.com/Adriandmen/05AB1E/wiki/Commands), 58 [bytes](https://github.com/Adriandmen/05AB1E/wiki/Codepage)

```
„I€ÜIÑ¨©OIÊi'€–}“€…íÀ‚³,ƒ«“®vy'+}\'=®ODI.S"==><"211S£sèIðý
```

[Try it online](https://tio.run/##yy9OTMpM/f//UcM8z0dNaw7P8Tw88dCKQyv9PQ93ZaoDRR41TK591DAHzFp2eO3hhkcNsw5t1jk26dBqoPChdWWV6tq1Meq2h9b5u3jqBSvZ2trZKBkZGgYfWlx8eIXn4Q2H9/7/bwYA) or [verify all test cases](https://tio.run/##yy9OTMpM/V9W6RJqr6TwqG2SgpL9/0cN8zwfNa05PCfi8MRDKw6t9I843JWpDhR51DC59lHDHDBr2eG1hxseNcw6tFnn2KRDq4HCh9aVVapr18ao2x5a5@8SoResZGtrZ6NkZGgYfGhx8eEVEYc3HN77X@d/tJmOoZGOoXEsAA).

**Explanation:**

```python
„I€Ü              # Push dictionary string "I am"
IÑ¨               # Push the divisors of the input-integer, with itself removed
   ©              # Store it in the register (without popping)
    O             # Get the sum of these divisors
     IÊi   }      # If it's not equal to the input-integer:
        '€–      '#  Push dictionary string "not"
“€…íÀ‚³,ƒ«“       # Push dictionary string "a perfect number, because"
®v   }            # Loop `y` over the divisors:
  y'+            '#  Push the divisor `y`, and the string "+" to the stack
      \           # Discard the final "+"
       '=        '# And push the string "="
®O                # Get the sum of the divisors again
  D               # Duplicate it
I.S               # Compare it to the input-integer (-1 if smaller; 0 if equal; 1 if larger)
   "==><"         # Push string "==><"
         211S£    # Split into parts of size [2,1,1]: ["==",">","<"]
              sè  # Index into it (where the -1 will wrap around to the last item)
I                 # Push the input-integer again
ðý                # Join everything on the stack by spaces
                  # (and output the result implicitly)
```

[See this 05AB1E tip of mine (section *How to use the dictionary?*)](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/166851/52210) to understand why `„I€Ü` is `"I am"`, `'€–` is `"not"`, and `“€…íÀ‚³,ƒ«“` is `"a perfect number, because"`.