# Smallest Narcissistic Number

Tags: code-golf, math

Given a natural numbers `n>1`, find the smallest narcissistic number of `n` digit.

A [narcissistic number](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Narcissistic_number) is a number which is the sum of its own digits, each raised to the power of the number of digits.

For example, for `n=3` (3 digits) the out put should be `153`:

`1^3 + 5^3 + 3^3 = 1 + 125 + 27 = 153`

For `n=4` (4 digits) the out put should be `1634`:

`1^4 + 6^4 + 3^4 + 4^4 = 1 + 1296 + 81 + 256 = 1634`

For `n=5` (5 digits) the out put should be `54748`:

`5^5 + 4^5 + 7^5 + 4^5 + 8^5 = 54748`

If there is no such numbers, like for example `n = 2` or `n = 22` output any special output (a negative number, an exception, an error, empty,...).

**Winning Criteria**

This is [code-golf](/questions/tagged/code-golf), so shortest answer in bytes by language wins.

[**OEIS A005188**](https://oeis.org/A005188)

Comment: What if there is no such numbers, like for `n = 2`

Comment: We've tested [whether a number is narcissistic](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/q/15244/48934), and then I've asked you guys to [output all narcissistic numbers](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/q/83272/48934) (because there are only 88 of them).

Comment: @GrzegorzPuławski question updated

Comment: @mdahmoune: Would looping indefinitely be acceptable when there is no number?

Comment: @Emigna No, any output but not infinite loop.

Comment: Is empty output acceptable in that case?

Comment: @Emigna yes of course.

Comment: It seems like `0` is a narcissistic number according to your definition. But the OEIS sequence starts at `1`. So what should we do?

Comment: Is hardcoding allowed?

Comment: @ThePirateBay yes hardcoding is allowed

Comment: @Arnauld consider that `n>1`, and output any thing for  `n==1 `

Comment: This is just a loop round an earlier question, and as such qualifies as a duplicate.

Answer (score 2):

## [05AB1E](https://github.com/Adriandmen/05AB1E), <s>16</s> 15 bytes

Very inefficient.
Empty output if there is no solution.

```
°LʒDSImOQ}ʒgQ}н
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##MzBNTDJM/f//0AafU5Ncgj1z/QNrT01KD6y9sPf/fxMA)

Answer (score 1):

## JavaScript (ES7), <s>82</s> 79 bytes

*Saved 3 bytes thanks to [@ThePirateBay](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/users/72349/thepiratebay)*

Returns `undefined` when there's no solution. Reasonably fast up to `n = 7` and really slow beyond that.

```js
n=>[...Array(10**n).keys()].find(x=>x==eval([...x+='0'].join(`**${n}+`))&&x[n])
```

#### Demo

```js
let f =

n=>[...Array(10**n).keys()].find(x=>x==eval([...x+='0'].join(`**${n}+`))&&x[n])

for(n = 2; n < 6; n++) {
  console.log(n, f(n))
}
```

---

## Recursive version, 72 bytes

Returns `"0"` (as a string) when there's no solution. For `n > 4`, it would require to either enable Tail-Call-Optimization (not tested) or extend the maximum size of the call stack.

```js
f=(n,x=1)=>eval([...s=x+'0'].join(`**${n}+`))-x|!s[n]?s[n+1]||f(n,x+1):x
```

```js
f=(n,x=1)=>eval([...s=x+'0'].join(`**${n}+`))-x|!s[n]?s[n+1]||f(n,x+1):x

for(n = 2; n < 5; n++) {
  console.log(n, f(n))
}
```

Answer (score 1):

## [Pyth](https://github.com/isaacg1/pyth), 20 bytes

```
hfqTsm^dQjT10r^TtQ^T
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##K6gsyfj/PyOtMKQ4Ny4lMCvE0KAoLqQkMC7k/39jAA)

How it works...

```
hfqTsm^dQjT10r^TtQ^T    Implicit: Q=input()

                  ^T    10^Q (final Q is inferred)
              ^TtQ      10^(Q-1)
             r          Range over the above
                           (generates list of numbers of length Q)
 f                      Filter each element in the above (as T) over...
         jT10              Get digits in T
     m                     Map each digit in the above (as d) over...
      ^dQ                     d^Q
    s                      Sum these
  qT                       Is the above equal to the original number?
h                       Take the first element of this filtered list
```

Throws an error if no solutions exist.

Comment: 16 bytes: ``f&qQl`Tqsm^dQjT;``

Comment: Abusing String-ification: `f&qQl\`Tqsm^sdQ\`` (15 bytes)