# Output the nth Even Perfect Number

Tags: code-golf, math, number

### Challenge

Given an integer, n, as input where `0 <= n <= 2^10`, output the nth even perfect number.

### Perfect Numbers

A perfect number is a number, x where the sum of its factors (excluding itself) equals x. For example, 6:

```
6: 1, 2, 3, 6
```

And, of course, `1 + 2 + 3 = 6`, so 6 is perfect.

If a perfect number, `x`, is even, `x mod 2 = 0`.

### Examples

The following are the first 10 even perfect numbers:

```
6
28
496
8128
33550336
8589869056
137438691328
2305843008139952128
2658455991569831744654692615953842176
191561942608236107294793378084303638130997321548169216
```

Note that you may index this however you wish: 6 may be the 1st or the 0th even perfect number.

### Winning

Shortest code in bytes wins.

Comment: Is there any odd perfect number?

Comment: @LeakyNun Yes, it appears there is

Comment: @LeakyNun I think, that is an open question. If this question was output the nth odd perfect number... You would need a billion rep bounty to get it solved. http://blogs.ams.org/mathgradblog/2013/07/25/odd-perfect-numbers-exist/ (none exist below 10^300)

Comment: What is the smallest odd perfect number?

Comment: Can we assume that there are no odd perfect numbers?

Comment: Is there an efficient implementation of this possible, I would imagine some intersting math can happen here.

Comment: @RohanJhunjhunwala There's an efficient-ish formula for *even* perfect numbers that involves Mersenne primes.

Comment: @Dennis What does an even perfect number mean here?

Comment: A perfect number that is divisible by 2.

Comment: @Dennis It's that simple? Oh.

Comment: An even number **n** is perfect iff there is a Mersenne prime **p** such that **n = p(p+1)/2**. There is no such formula for odd perfect numbers; moreover, it is unknown if odd perfect numbers even exist.

Comment: @Dennis So, for the range `0 <= n <= 2^10` it's perfectly acceptable to use that formula

Comment: [Related.](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/q/58026/8478) [Related.](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/q/44814/8478)

Comment: Not quite. There are only **49** known Mersenne primes.

Comment: If our language is bounded for a maximum number of `2^64-1`, are we allowed to assume that the output will never be larger than that?

Comment: How should one respond to an input of $n=60?$

Comment: @RossMillikan What's special about n=60?

Comment: @BetaDecay:  it is greater than $49$, so the 60th perfect number is not known.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

## [Jelly](https://github.com/DennisMitchell/jelly), 7 bytes

```
6Æṣ=$#Ṫ
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##y0rNyan8/9/scNvDnYttVZQf7lz1//9/EwA)

#### How it works

```
6Æṣ=$#Ṫ  Main link. Argument: n

6        Set the return value to 6.
     #   Execute the link to the left with argument k = 6, 7, 8, ... until n
         values of k result in a truthy value. Yield the array of matches.
    $        Combine the two links to the left into a monadic chain.
 Æṣ              Compute the sum of k's proper divisors.
   =             Compare the result with k.
      Ṫ  Tail; extract the last match.
```

Comment: So many builtins regarding divisors...

Answer (score 6):

## Mathematica, 13 bytes

Not surprisingly, there is a built-in.

```
PerfectNumber
```

Example:

```
In[1]:= PerfectNumber[18]                                                       

Out[1]= 33570832131986724437010877211080384841138028499879725454996241573482158\

>    45044404288204877880943769038844953577426084988557369475990617384115743842\

>    47301308070476236559422361748505091085378276585906423254824947614731965790\

>    74656099918600764404702181660294469121778737965822199901663478093006075022\

>    35922320184998563614417718592540207818507301504509772708485946474363553778\

>    15002849158802448863064617859829560720600134749556178514816801859885571366\

>    09224841817877083608951191123174885226416130683197710667392351007374503755\

>    40335253147622794359007165170269759424103195552989897121800121464177467313\

>    49444715625609571796578815564191221029354502997518133405151709561679510954\

>    53649485576150660101689160658011770193274226308280507786835049549112576654\

>    51011967045674593989019420525517538448448990932896764698816315598247156499\

>    81962616327512831278795091980742531934095804545624886643834653798850027355\

>    06153988851506645137759275553988219425439764732399824712438125054117523837\

>    43825674443705501944105100648997234160911797840456379499200487305751845574\

>    87014449512383771396204942879824895298272331406370148374088561561995154576\

>    69607964052126908149265601786094447595560440059050091763547114092255371397\

>    42580786755435211254219478481549478427620117084594927467463298521042107553\

>    17849183589266903954636497214522654057134843880439116344854323586388066453\

>    13826206591131266232422007835577345584225720310518698143376736219283021119\

>    28761789614688558486006504887631570108879621959364082631162227332803560330\

>    94756423908044994601567978553610182466961012539222545672409083153854682409\

>    31846166962495983407607141601251889544407008815874744654769507268678051757\

>    74695689121248545626112138666740771113961907153092335582317866270537439303\

>    50490226038824797423347994071302801487692985977437781930503487497407869280\

>    96033906295910199238181338557856978191860647256209708168229116156300978059\

>    19702685572687764976707268496046345276316038409383829227754491185785965832\

>    8888332628525056
```

Comment: I think there is a standard loophole for that?

Comment: @PaŭloEbermann correct, with 19 downvotes and a comment with 94 upvotes approving of it: https://codegolf.meta.stackexchange.com/a/1078/32933

Answer (score 4):

## [MATL](https://github.com/lmendo/MATL), 15 bytes

```
`@Z\s@E=vtsG<}n
```

Very slow. It keeps trying increasing numbers one by one until the *n*-th perfect number is found.

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##y00syfn/P8EhKqbYwdW2rKTY3aY27/9/YwA)

#### Explanation

```
`        % Do...while
  @      %   Push iteration index, k (starting at 1)
  Z\     %   Array of divisors
  s      %   Sum
  @E     %   Push k. Multiply by 2
  =      %   Equal? If so, k is a perfect number
  v      %   Concatenate vertically. This gradually builds an array which at the k-th
         %   iteration contains k zero/one values, where ones indicate perfect numbers
  ts     %   Duplicate. Sum of array
  G<     %   Push input. Less than? This is the loop condition: if true, proceed with
         %   next iteration
}        % Finally (execute right before exiting loop)
  n      %   Number of elements of the array
         % End (implicit). Display (implicit)
```

Answer (score 3):

## [Pyth](https://github.com/isaacg1/pyth), 13 bytes

```
e.fqsf!%ZTStZ
```

[Try it online!](http://pyth.herokuapp.com/?code=e.fqsf%21%25ZTStZ&input=3&debug=0)

Please do not try any higher number. It just tests the even numbers one by one.

Answer (score 2):

## [05AB1E](https://github.com/Adriandmen/05AB1E), 8 bytes

```
µNNÑ¨OQ½
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##MzBNTDJM/f//0Fa/wx1@focnHlrhHxhwaO///yYA)

**Explanation**

```
µ          # loop over increasing N until counter equals input
 N         # push N
  NÑ       # push factors of N
    ¨      # remove last factor (itself)
     O     # sum factors
      Q    # compare the sum to N for equality
       ½   # if true, increase counter
```

Answer (score 2):

## [Python 2](https://docs.python.org/2/),  <s>198  153 83 78 77 75</s> 74 bytes

```python
i=input()
j=0
while i:j+=1;i-=sum(x*(j%x<1)for x in range(1,j))==j
print j
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##BcE7DoAgDADQnVN0MQE/iRgntYdxUGmjhSBGPD2@F77kvAylEJKEJ2mjGHv1Ojo3oIkbtDN1eD@XzrXmKi/W7D5CBhKIqxybti0bg8gqRJIEXMr4Aw)

Now it just reads like psuedocode.

- Saved <s>45</s> Countless Bytes because @Leaky Nun taught me about the sum function and list comprehension.
- Saved 2 bytes thanks to @shooqie's suggestion to remove the uncessary brackets.

We just iterate through every even number until we have found n perfect numbers.

Comment: notice that your `g` is actually just `sum`.

Comment: @LeakyNun serves me right, for not knowing the python libraries. I really should learn more than just java and SILOS.

Comment: [Also, I've replaced your `f` with a list comprehension](https://tio.run/##Fcs9DoMwDEDhOTmFF6REZQDEVNUnqRgY@LFDTZQGEU4fwvCmp89fcd2ly5mQxB/RWM3YaFc6V9omcB96a8UvbLWiGf7Hz3wTzHuABCQQRlkm09Zsy@QqITaDReRilHuQDyQROOf@Bg)

Comment: [more golfings](https://tio.run/##DcNLDkAwEADQfU8xG0kbFogV5iRiYeEzU0ZTFXX68pLn3rCdUqdESOLuoI1iLJX9PxvtM9ieWs6x6myO133oIcJyeohAAn6SddZVwYYW4CwilqNBZOU8SQBOqfkA)

Comment: [no need for `k`, just decrement `i`](https://tio.run/##BcFBCoAgEADAu6/YS6BUkNGp2JdEhw6Vu9QmpmSvtxn/RXdLXwohiU9RG8XYqdfRuQGNXKOdqMUnXXrOsN8BMpBAWOXYtG3Y0A5cZcRuMYisfCCJwKUMPw).

Comment: @LeakyNun \o/ <s>we</s> you broke 80 bytes!

Comment: time to learn more about list comprehension

Comment: And you can replace `==0` by `<1`

Comment: @LeakyNun Does python have any standard libraries to factorize a number?

Comment: Also, you don't need square brackets (at least in Python 3)

Comment: It doesn't have a standard library to factorize a number; if it had, it would probably cost more bytes to import it.

Comment: [74 bytes](https://tio.run/##BcE7DoAgDADQnVN0MQE/iRgntYdxUGmjhSBGPD2@F77kvAylEJKEJ2mjGHv1Ojo3oIkbtDN1eD@XzrXmKi/W7D5CBhKIqxybti0bg8gqRJIEXMr4Aw)

Comment: \o/ but it,s a shame we are still 6 bytes away from java script. Perhaps this can become an anonymous function or something?

Answer (score 2):

## PHP, 111 Bytes

0-Indexing

Works with the concept that a perfect number is a number where `n=x*y`
`x=2^i` and `y=2^(i+1)-1` and y must be prime

```
for(;!$r[$argn];$u?:$r[]=$z)for($z=2**++$n*($y=2**($n+1)-1),$u=0,$j=1;$j++<sqrt($y);)$y%$j?:$u++;echo$r[$argn];
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##RYwxDsIwEAR7foG0SD5fkDAFBZdTHoJSIARYLhxjcJF83jg0dLs7q0k@1X5IPm1wzc@oJ6mPKRvZIl9@yygow7m1UbHQyrDo0VpmRGswr9kgsqO9ow5FDx2COkFg7t@v/GkfEsK8Q2iewiz3m5/@@lq/)

Answer (score 1):

## [Python 3](https://docs.python.org/3/), 69 bytes

```python
f=lambda n,k=1:n and-~f(n-(sum(j>>k%j*j for j in range(1,k))==k),k+1)
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##DcMxDsIgFADQ3VP8xRT014h1MqEXUQe0oED5EKBDF6@OfclLa/1GGpoNKeYKZS277anomvV7ycVGmm2wlYnzhjcjZxVekwJCL8WNQNHU/wyjnpUlMDeOfu8ODkzM4MASZEUfzQR6zqX0HP1R8JaypcoOQSVm8C4QLggDwvXJEYpOIKF7UMfbHw)

Answer (score 1):

**Scala, 103 bytes**

```
n=>Stream.from(1).filter(_%2==0).filter(x=>Stream.from(1).take(x-1).filter(x%_==0).sum==x).drop(n).head
```

Answer (score 1):

## Haskell, 61 Bytes

```
(!!)(filter(\x->x==sum[n|n<-[1..x-1],x`mod`n==0]||x==1)[1..])
```

Comment: Since the index can start at 0, you don't need the `||x==1`. You can also save bytes by moving the `!!` just before the closing parenthesis to make an operator section, and by replacing the `filter` with another list comprehension.

Answer (score 1):

## [Haskell](https://www.haskell.org/), 52 bytes

```hs
([n|n<-[1..],n==sum[d|d<-[1..div n 2],mod n d<1]]!!)
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##y0gszk7Nyfn/P81WIzqvJs9GN9pQTy9WJ8/Wtrg0NzqlJgUikpJZppCnYBSrk5ufAmSk2BjGxioqav7PTczMsy1KTUzxybOzsy0oyswrUdBTSPtvBAA)

Starts at n = 0. Not particularly fast

Comment: By our consensus, it's valid to omit the `f=` from the byte count.

Answer (score 0):

## JavaScript (ES6), 68 bytes

```
n=>eval(`for(x=5;n;s||n--)for(f=s=++x;f--;)(x/f-(x/f|0))||(s-=f);x`)
```

```js
F=n=>eval('for(x=5;n;s||n--)for(f=s=++x;f--;)(x/f-(x/f|0))||(s-=f);x')

console.log(
  F(1),
  F(2),
  F(3),
  //F(4),
  //F(5),
)
```

Answer (score 0):

## [Perl 6](http://perl6.org/), 42 bytes

```
{(grep {$_==[+] grep $_%%*,^$_},^∞)[$_]}
```

The input index is 1-based.

Answer (score 0):

### Clojure, 79 bytes

```
#(nth(for[i(range):when(=(apply +(for[j(range 1 i):when(=(mod i j)0)]j))i)]i)%)
```

Following the spec, heavy usage of for's `:when` condition.

Answer (score 0):

## [PowerShell](https://github.com/TryItOnline/TioSetup/wiki/Powershell), 152 bytes

```powershell
$ErrorActionPreference='SilentlyContinue'
function p{param($x)(1..($x-1)|?{!($x%$_)})|%{$s+=$_};$s}
1..$args[0]|%{if(((p -x $_)-eq$_)-and(!($_%2))){$_}}
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##HYvRCoIwGIXvfQqDiRuhaF2GRET3QZcRMuzXBmtb/5SMuWdfq5tzDpzvM/oNaB8gZQjkhKjx0I1CqzNCDwiqgya/CAlqlJ@jVqNQE@RJP6k/lRpnOPInJTOjdVnGLmq27N0qroy0zLMlc8SuG9L6HbE@iRDhONhrdYuP6CmlJi3mNLIFvH7J1Z1Gvc02jDEXPR9C2FZf)