# Generalise perfect numbers

Tags: code-golf, math, sequence, number-theory

Let \$\sigma(n)\$ represent the divisor sum of \$n\$ and \$\sigma^m(n)\$ represent the [repeated application](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Iterated_function) of the divisor function \$m\$ times.

[Perfect numbers](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Perfect_number) are numbers whose divisor sum equals their double or \$\sigma(n) = 2n\$. For example, \$\sigma(6) = 12 = 2\times6\$

[Superperfect numbers](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Superperfect_number) are numbers whose twice iterated divisor sum equals their double. For example, \$\sigma^2(16) = \sigma(\sigma(16)) = \sigma(31) = 32 = 2\times16\$

[\$m\$-superperfect numbers](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Superperfect_number#Generalizations) are numbers such that \$\sigma^m(n) = 2n\$ for \$m \ge 1\$. For \$m \ge 3\$, there are no such numbers.

[\$(m,k)\$-perfect numbers](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Superperfect_number#Generalizations) are numbers such that \$\sigma^m(n) = kn\$. For example, \$\sigma^3(12) = 120 = 12\times10\$, so \$12\$ is a \$(3,10)\$-perfect number.

You are to choose one of the following three tasks to do:

- Take three positive integers \$n, m, k\$ and output the \$n\$th \$(m,k)\$-perfect number (0 or 1 indexed, your choice)
- Take three positive integers \$n, m, k\$ and output the first \$n\$ \$(m,k)\$-perfect numbers
- Take two positive integers \$m, k\$ and output all \$(m,k)\$-perfect numbers

You may assume that the inputs will never represent an impossible sequence (e.g. \$m = 5, k = 2\$) and that the sequences are all infinite in length. You may take input in [any convenient method](https://codegolf.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/2447/default-for-code-golf-input-output-methods).

Note that methods that count up starting from either \$m\$ or \$k\$ are not valid, as they fail for \$(4,4)\$-perfect numbers, the smallest of which is \$2\$ (credit to [Carl Schildkraut](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/4045163/427632) for finding this)

This is [code-golf](/questions/tagged/code-golf) so the shortest code in bytes wins.

---

### Test cases

This lists the first few outputs\${}^*\$ for example inputs of \$(m, k)\$

```
m, k -> out
3, 10 -> 12, 156, 32704, ...
2, 2 -> 2, 4, 16, 64, 4096, 65536, ...
1, 2 -> 6, 28, 496, 8128, ...
4, 48 -> 160, 455, 5920, ...
3, 28 -> 4480, ...
3, 16 -> 294, 6882, ...
1, 4 -> 30240, 32760, ...
4, 4 -> 2, ...
```

<sub>\${}^*\$: Aka, the outputs I could get from my generating program without timing out on TIO</sub>

Comment: [Sandbox](https://codegolf.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/2140/sandbox-for-proposed-challenges/20796#20796). [Related](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/211028/n-perfect-numbers). Brownie points for beating my 9 byte Jelly answer

Answer (score 5):

## [PowerShell](https://github.com/TryItOnline/TioSetup/wiki/Powershell), <strike>95 92</strike> 87 bytes

-8 bytes thanks to mazzy!

This takes two parameters, m and k, and calculates all (m,k) perfect numbers (up to the maximum for a 64-bit signed integer).

```powershell
param($m,$k)for(;$n=++$x){1..$m|%{$a=0;1..$n|%{$a+=$_*!($n%$_)};$n=$a}
,$x*!($a-$k*$x)}
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##HYtBCoAgFAX33SJ4gaZF0TI8S/xFEZgWtigwz/7LljPMHPs1h3Odt435oEBOwGlYuexBjPBGKdwy9m0L91QRZLoxg/9BGUx1KeArTDLlHJQKjTtLamDrb07MPHDfvQ)

Comment: `$x=1` instead `$x=$n=1`?

Comment: @mazzy Good spot!

Comment: `$x=1` is redundant. and  `,$x*!($a-$k*$x)` instead `,$x*($a-eq$k*$x)`. [Try it online!](https://tio.run/##HYtBCoAgFAX33SJ4gaZF0TI8S/xFEZgWtigwz/7LljPMHPs1h3Odt435oEBOwGlYuexBjPBGKdwy9m0L91QRZLoxg/9BGUx1KeArTDLlHJQKjTtLamDrb07MPHDfvQ "PowerShell – Try It Online"). thanks Zaelin, smart solution

Comment: Ahhhh, I had the x=1 in there because I was testing it in a console, so x needed reset every time; definitely wouldn't have thought to cut it; smart saves! Thanks again @mazzy!

Answer (score 5):

## [05AB1E](https://github.com/Adriandmen/05AB1E), <s>11</s> 10 bytes

-1 byte thanks to [Kevin Cruijssen](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/users/52210/kevin-cruijssen)!

Outputs the infinite sequence given \$m\$ and \$k\$.

```
∞ʒ¹FÑO}y/Q
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##yy9OTMpM/f//Uce8U5MO7XQ7PNG/tlI/8P9/Yy5DAwA)

```python
∞            # push an infinite list of positice integers
 ʒ           # iterate over the list and keep y if:
  ¹          # push the first input m
   F  }      # iterate m times:
    ÑO       # take sum O of divisors Ñ
             # sigma^m(y)
       y/    # divide by y
         Q   # is this equal to the second input k?
             # sigma^m(y) / y == k
```

Comment: I'm not entirely sure, but I think you can remove the `²` and use implicit inputs. It will in that case incorrectly multiply the first input \$m\$ with \$1\$ in the first iteration, but I think (based on the test cases, so I'm not sure) \$1\$ will never be in the output anyway, so it shouldn't matter. But it's likely a counter-example could be found where it might incorrectly result in truthy for \$1\$ if you have \$m\$ instead of \$k\$ in the first iteration? Not sure how to prove or disprove my hunch.

Comment: @KevinCruijssen this fails for \$m=1\$ and any \$k>1\$ as \$\sigma(1)=1\$. I remember spending some time on trying to use implicit input here without success.

Comment: Hmm, and if you swap the two, and use the implicit second input after dividing by the current number at the end: `∞ʒ¹FÑO}y/Q`? (Not sure how floating point inaccuracies might affect the results, though.)

Comment: @KevinCruijssen thanks a lot, this does work :). And as long as k is reasonably small, no floating point issues should occur.

Answer (score 3):

## [Jelly](https://github.com/DennisMitchell/jelly), 9 [bytes](https://github.com/DennisMitchell/jelly/wiki/Code-page)

```
1Æs⁴¡÷¥Ƒ#
```

A full program accepting `k m n` which prints a list representation of the first `n` \$k\$-\$m\$-generalised-perfect-numbers.

**[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##y0rNyan8/9/wcFvxo8YthxYe3n5o6bGJyv@BQgb/jf8bAQA)**

#### How?

```
1Æs⁴¡÷¥Ƒ# - Main Link: k
1       # - count up from j=1 & find the first (3rd argument, n) truthy results of f(j, k):
       Ƒ  -   is (j) invariant under?:
      ¥   -     last two links as a dyad - g(j, k):
    ¡     -       repeated application...
   ⁴      -         ...number of times: 1st argument, m
 Æs       -         ...action: divisor sum
     ÷    -       divide (by k)
```

Comment: Is it guaranteed that `k` will always be less than or equal to the first output? If so, I think I can save a byte on mine

Comment: I thought so as I wrote the code, but now I'm not so sure... deleting for now.

Comment: @cairdcoinheringaahing I've rewritten to start counting up from \$m\$, but I do feel like \$k\$ might actually be OK (but can't prove it). Can you save 1 by counting up from \$k\$?

Comment: Unfortunately neither \$m\$ nor \$k\$ are valid starts, as demonstrated in [this](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/4045163/427632) Math.SE question: \$2\$ is a \$(4,4)\$-perfect number. I’ll add that as an example test case when I get back to a computer

Comment: @cairdcoinheringaahing Heh, brain fail I guess. Updated to a (and most probably, your) nine byter.

Comment: Mine was [this](https://tio.run/##y0rNyan8/9/wcFvxo8YthxbaHp5@crryf6CIwX/j/0YA) actually, but nice use of `Ƒ`!

Answer (score 3):

## [Husk](https://github.com/barbuz/Husk), 14 bytes

```
fS=ö/⁰!²t¡oΣḊN
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##ASoA1f9odXNr/@KGkTLigoH/ZlM9w7Yv4oGwIcKydMKhb86j4biKTv///zP/MTA)

Outputs the infinite sequence of (m [arg1], k [arg2])-perfect numbers.  TIO header gets just the first two terms, to avoid timing-out.

```
             N   # from the sequence N of all integers, 
f                # output the elements that are truthy with this function:
         ¡o      # construct an infinite list by repeatedly getting
           ΣḊ    # the sum of divisors;
        t        # discard the first element,
      !²         # and get the element at index given by arg1,
    /⁰           # then divide it by arg2,
 S=ö             # and check whether it's equal to the original number
```

Answer (score 2):

## [Wolfram Language (Mathematica)](https://www.wolfram.com/wolframscript/), 49 bytes

outputs all (m,k)

```
Do[Nest[Tr@*Divisors,n,#]==n#2&&Print@n,{n,∞}]&
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##y00syUjNTSzJTE78n2773yU/2i@1uCQ6pMhByyWzLLM4v6hYJ09HOdbWNk/ZSE0toCgzr8QhT6c6T@dRx7zaWLX/YBEFh/RoYx1Dg9j//wE)

-3 bytes from @att

Comment: [49 bytes](https://tio.run/##y00syUjNTSzJTE78n2773yU/2i@1uCQ6pMhByyWzLLM4v6hYJ09HOdbWNk/ZSE0toCgzr8QhT6c6T@dRx7zaWLX/YBEFh/RoYx1Dg9j//wE)

Answer (score 2):

## [Python 3](https://docs.python.org/3/), <s>139</s> 123 bytes

```python
g=lambda n,m:m and g(n+sum(i*(n%i<1)for i in range(1,n)),m-1)or n
f=lambda m,k,n,x=1:n and f(m,k,n-(g(x,m)==k*x),x+1)or x-1
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##TY/dCoMwDEbvfYogDBqNsKgXQ@ZeZOzC4XTFNYpz0D29q3@4Qujh4@Sj7b7Ds5VkHOv8VZh7WYCQyQwUUkKtJHx/jNKBkoM@M1ZtDxq0QF9I/VBMgkgmYnS5eNXWYKghIZtzJnNPpeYkUrWyZDDPm8Ai2XDesxGPU68haAhkar@qhICPbpBg43ji2N1rvOBfmuyYTsi7y7vLu5s68bQaK8d4yzxwp@u1DMuzyY8uPm2fQBx/)

Very direct approach, brute-forces for every number and runs until a result is found.

Answer (score 2):

## Scala `-language:postfixOps`, 80 bytes

```scala
m=>k=>Stream from 2 filter(n=>(n/:1.to(m))((n,_)=>1 to n filter(n%_<1)sum)==k*n)
```

[Try it online!](https://scastie.scala-lang.org/aM1eBJ1xT8ykeKvSKFZ1qQ)

Outputs all (m, k)-perfect numbers. The flag just saves a couple bytes, but why not use it?

```
m=>k=>                     //Curried arguments
  Stream from 2            //Infinite stream of integers starting at 2
    filter(n=>             //Filter every n in the Stream according to this predicate
      k*n==                  //Check if k * n equals
                              //The iterated divisor sum
        (n/:1.to(m))          //Fold left over the range [1..m] starting with n
                              //We don't actually care about the values in [1..m], it's just to repeatedly find the divisor sum
          ((n,_)=>              //Find the divisor sum of the left argument:
            1 to n               //Range [1..n] of possible divisors
              filter(n%_<1)      //Filter the ones that divide n
              sum                //Sum them
          )
  )
```

Answer (score 2):

## [Python 2](https://docs.python.org/2/), 94 bytes

Takes two positive integers \$ m,k \$ and outputs all \$(m,k)\$-perfect numbers.

```python
def f(m,k,n=1):
 s=n;exec"i=t=s\nwhile~-i:i-=1;s+=i>>t%i*t\n"*m
 if s==k*n:print n
 f(m,k,n+1)
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##NYzLDoIwEADv/YqGxITyMFZPQpYv4YZt2ECXprtGufjrFQ9OMseZuMu80TVjiFsSzTurwzM7SW56JsaNVgwo5f2HyQ/ntS9DszQE1nRKM1Dv3m4qEAR4pNeMq/u02GELtucacBjkhJWMVFRBafRHAktFXUxIokn9f7U12Ze3RtuLyV8)

A straightforward implementation of the problem. The one obfuscation used is the `s+=i>>t%i*t`, which is equivalent to `s+=i*(t%i<1)`, or `if t%i<1:s+=i`.

Answer (score 2):

## [Stax](https://github.com/tomtheisen/stax), 13 [bytes](https://github.com/tomtheisen/stax/blob/master/docs/packed.md#packed-stax)

```
ü╩╔◘8┌╜♀ñêP=e
```

[Run and debug it](https://staxlang.xyz/#p=81cac90838dabd0ca488503d65&i=3,10)

the divisor sum part takes a lot of space due to two byte builtins.

Outputs the sequence for `m,k` infinitely.

Answer (score 2):

## JavaScript (V8), 119 bytes

```
f=(m,k,i=1)=>((g=x=>(s=[...Array(x+1).keys()].reduce((a,b)=>a+(x%b<1)*b),--t?g(s):s))(i,t=m)==k*i&&print(i),f(m,k,i+1))
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##JY1BCsIwEABfY9ltN8HgRcRVfId4SGpSYmgpSSzp62PA01yGmY/edBqjX7PYzrU6hpkCeVbIN4CJS0Pip5TyEaPeoQwKZbB7AnzJaN/f0QJoMk3XA5SDuSrsDZIQ@T5BwktCBE@ZZ2QOve@6Nfolg0dy/1ULYnVwInXE@gM)

Answer (score 2):

## JavaScript (ES6), 86 bytes

Expects `(m,k,n)` and returns the \$n\$<sup>th</sup> \$(m,k)\$-perfect number (1-indexed).

```javascript
(m,k,n)=>{for(i=0;n;n-=s==i*k)for(M=m,s=++i,d=0;d||(j=d=s,M--);)s+=j%--d?0:d;return i}
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##PY7PboMwDIfvPIUPnZqUJCIUTVORO@2wY58AoRXxZws0SZV0kybaZ2cpnTjZn3/@LPfVT@Vrp84XbmzTTh1ORLOBGYr7sbOOKExykxuOHlFtBnqfHVAzj3GsWBPS5nolPTbo2YFzmlMfY//EefOa7JrctZdvZ0DdpryIAIotA5kwSEt2pzR0DLIHyBm2D8jC@GXZC1YaSC4kn5csaNkC2QyyjMpIhE/fq/qLkEIzGBiYkgLuobbG21MrTvaTHDWuRn0LcajDbQersRBCvDlX/RJDS6GrMyEfwZ3VjvxfghgkpaK3ypA1gzUNJ4J3pHT6Aw)

Answer (score 2):

## [Haskell](https://www.haskell.org/), 76 bytes

```hs
f m k n=take n[r|r<-[1..],r*k==iterate(\a->sum[x|x<-[1..a],a`mod`x==0])r!!m]
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##JclBCoMwEAXQq3yhC1tUrNBdpxeJAQeMGOKkMqaQhXdPC@Ut38pHcNtWygJBQKTEwSEaPfXZmnvX2UZvgcgnp5xcPXL7Oj5i8pn/z7bhSd7zlIl6e9WqEluEfQRhVx8TLlgw/DzKFw)

- returns first n terms

Answer (score 1):

## [Charcoal](https://github.com/somebody1234/Charcoal), 43 bytes

```
ＮθＮηＮζ≔¹εＷ‹ⅉθ«≦⊕ε≔εδＦη≔ΣΦ…·¹δ¬﹪δλδ¿⁼δ×εζ⟦Ｉε
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##XY09C8JADIZn/RUZc1AHxc1JREFQEXURcTjb1B5c7@x9KCj@9jPFDmK2J@@bPHklXW6lTmlpbjFsYn0hh42Y9H@5@uMn89R7dTU4zICYHpXSBLgi7/GIIoNGCHj1e2t564pLkzuqyQQqvie9LqAMihZL64BN0K33scaF0oF1fKqjV3faSXOlVlmwYWMDrm0RtUX@qAVP90mVgPMmSu3b5KBq8q3lyQ3YOmUCnmbSByRx5vo7pTGMYJQGd/0B) Link is to verbose version of code. Explanation:

```
ＮθＮηＮζ
```

Input `n`, `m` and `k`.

```
≔¹ε
```

Initialise the loop at one.

```
Ｗ‹ⅉθ«
```

Repeat until `n` values have been output.

```
≦⊕ε
```

Try the next integer.

```
≔εδ
```

Make a copy of it.

```
Ｆη
```

Repeat `m` times...

```
≔ΣΦ…·¹δ¬﹪δλδ
```

... replace the copy with the sum of its divisors.

```
¿⁼δ×εζ
```

If the result is `k` times the loop counter, ...

```
⟦Ｉε
```

Output the loop counter on its own line.

Answer (score 1):

## [Japt](https://github.com/ETHproductions/japt), <s>18</s> 16 [bytes](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ISO/IEC_8859-1)

```
È*V¥_â x}g[X]}iW
```

[Try it](https://petershaggynoble.github.io/Japt-Interpreter/?v=1.4.6&code=yCpWpV/iIHh9Z1tYXX1pVw&input=MgoyCjU)

```
Prints nth element 1-indexed

1st input(U) = m
2nd input(V) = k
3rd input(W) = n

@ ... }iW   - return W-th number that satisfy Om(n)==kn
_â x}         - sum of divisors
     g[X]     - repeated U times starting with X
         ¥X*V - ==kn ?
```

Answer (score 1):

## [Clojure](https://clojure.org/), 112 bytes

```clj
#(rest(for[i(range):when(=(* %2 i)(nth(iterate(fn[j](apply + j(for[k(range 1 j):when(=(rem j k)0)]k)))i)%1))]i))
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##PY3BasMwEETv/oqBENhNLpGihFLIlwgdTLNqJDmyoyiUfr1rOdDTG9h5O1/DGF9FZrqKh583VORZyY/FBip9/hb@/LlJpgvtsNUITLneKFQpfRXy2UZH/TQNv9gjrl56e1CI/26ROyISH9glZg68VcwuMM/c0XV8ygPWZtyRnO2swhHq4Dp7goZeaJZnjUcYmA/3bugWdKue16Bg1otpdK6jqYRchwyqfRIs9G1gmef5Dw)

Anonymous function that returns an infinite lazy sequence of all \$(m,k)\$-perfect numbers.

Test suite extracts \$n\$ first members of the sequences, albeit a bit fewer than in the task specification in order to fit within a minute on TIO.