# How hyperperfect am I?

Tags: code-golf, math, number-theory

A [\$k\$-hyperperfect number](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hyperperfect_number) is a natural number \$n \ge 1\$ such that

$$n = 1 + k(\sigma(n) − n − 1)$$

where [\$\sigma(n)\$](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Divisor_function) is the sum of the divisors of \$n\$. Note that \$\sigma(n) - n\$ is the [proper divisor sum](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Aliquot_sum) of \$n\$. The sequence of \$k\$-hyperperfect numbers begins

$$6, 21, 28, 301, 325, 496, 697, \dots$$

This is [A034897](https://oeis.org/A034897) on the OEIS.

For example:

$$\begin{align}
\sigma(21) & = 1 + 3 + 7 + 21 = 32 \\
21 & = 1 + 2(32 - 21 - 1) \\
& = 1 + 2 \times 10 \\
& = 21
\end{align}$$

Therefore, \$21\$ is a \$2\$-hyperperfect number.

---

You are to take a \$k\$-hyperperfect number \$n\$ as input and output the value of \$k\$. You can assume you will never have to handle numbers greater than your language's limit at any point (i.e. \$k\sigma(n)\$ will always be within the bounds of your language), and you may input and output in any [convenient format](https://codegolf.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/2447/default-for-code-golf-input-output-methods).

The input is guaranteed to be a \$k\$-hyperperfect number, you don't have to handle inputs such as \$2, 87, 104\$ etc. that aren't \$k\$-hyperperfect.

This is [code-golf](/questions/tagged/code-golf), so the shortest code in bytes wins.

### Test cases

These are the outputs for all the listed values in the OEIS for this sequence, and are the exhaustive list of inputs for \$n < 1055834\$

```
      n       k
      6       1
     21       2
     28       1
    301       6
    325       3
    496       1
    697      12
   1333      18
   1909      18
   2041      12
   2133       2
   3901      30
   8128       1
  10693      11
  16513       6
  19521       2
  24601      60
  26977      48
  51301      19
  96361     132
 130153     132
 159841      10
 163201     192
 176661       2
 214273      31
 250321     168
 275833     108
 296341      66
 306181      35
 389593     252
 486877      78
 495529     132
 542413     342
 808861     366
1005421     390
1005649     168
1055833     348
```

Comment: [Related](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/q/220032/66833). [Related](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/q/211028/66833). Brownie points for beating my 7 byte Jelly answer

Comment: They missed a chance to call them "hyperfect" numbers

Comment: @JoKing Your comment made me realize that it was _**not**_ spelled "hyperfect". :-p

Answer (score 13):

## [Jelly](https://github.com/DennisMitchell/jelly), 5 bytes

```
:Æṣ’$
```

```
:       integer divide
Æṣ’$    the decremented divisor sum
```

This uses \$\lfloor\frac{n}{\sigma(n)-n-1}\rfloor\$ instead of \$\frac{n-1}{\sigma(n)-n-1}\$, but it still works because \$\frac{1}{\sigma(n)-n-1}\$ can never be greater than or equal to 1.

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##LY67cQMxDERbuUCJZi7A/wCpAFXiRHMNKHNk1aDYVTi@SuxGKCzHAckl8LCL@8e@P8a4HF@/P99/n6/TuB7P822MWBfhPrkuSi1UfF2suhy1rQurat9F1QwZSEZFC3Ay5piiAIXzZH0aWoCQdmmb7uBXocEwJXagXglLDhW0eYuIGWGydV@cdHptngiVngevFJx4sxzJlpFIsXKXXtRNDKskZc48oi79i7CCcFi@AQ)

Answer (score 8):

## [J](http://jsoftware.com/), <sup>24 23</sup> 20 bytes

```
<.@%1<:@#.[:I.0=i.|]
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##XVHLSsUwEN37FUGRi6BhHplpptzCBUEQXLkVVxcv6sYf8N9r28mU1kUW52RyHpPv8TofLmno0yHdJ0j9dB5yenx9eRqP@XSLx/50k9/65wzDV/59H@@uPs6fPwnTkC5JHdACCLdXVB3pghjaJTsk2c4Wa0LoSmpdw3XByMx7wsB2LwgK7rPECwZ3NNjFqxgB0QkENd5GRhXkrSaaREV1USoaqsWD0RQ9stvCTCKrM7uQKes/ah6S6OjiKFajFFobUybYFcVONcS4bR4LdaGlLZcAr/8DjeukxpbUO9MULTxZ2s8p1rAUN@VqEsvqXKxUrWvzVqqYCLV/4uKcFCqxVm6uFWpdO1hrDzCN4r7FTGpZFYOUucf4Bw)

<sup>-3 thanks to [rak's rounding down trick](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/223678/15469)</sup>

Let `n` be the input.

- `<.@%` round down n divided by
- `1<:@#.` 1 minus the sum of
- `[:I.` the indexes where
- `0=` 0 is equal to the remainder when
- `i.` the list 0..n-1
- `|` is divided elementwise into
- `]` n.

Answer (score 7):

## JavaScript (ES6), 36 bytes

```javascript
n=>~-n/(g=k=>~k--&&!(n%k)*k+g(k))(n)
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##VY7BUsIwEEDvfMXKjCQRG5oGK9UpnvTohSNwqCWtpSWpaXF0HP0CZ7x41P/we/gBP6HG0irkkN03u/t2l8F9UIQ6yUtLqoWoIr@S/vjFkgMc@6nJUsvq9Q6wPEzJUdqPcUoIlqTS4m6daIFRVCBCtQgWV0kmJo8yxDahpZqUOpExJrTIs6TE3ZnsEhopfRmEt7gAfwxPHYApyGMQD7kIS7GAOfhQUDO4@psbQH9A6CrI8fV6dSM0OTdToZKFygTNVIynRqCFEUJkzmpy/995Aej7623z8W5@BGeANp@vaE6XKpEYzUpEjPGZVFA/dxuAdergsIadhkd7dW63dXfLzknDvOaht@9zvdMGax/jnDc8qtmzvV127CHb7XdY27@9h3vtfm7/8ojt3cds12v97Ac)

#### How?

\$\sigma(n) − n − 1\$ is the sum of the divisors of \$n\$ in \$[2..n-1]\$. This is also the sum of the divisors of \$n\$ in \$[-1..n-1]\$ because \$1\$ and \$-1\$ cancel each other out. The helper function \$g\$ computes the latter, so that we can use the slightly more golf-friendly halt condition `~k--`.

**Note**: From a mathematical perspective, we really should remove \$0\$ from the list of possible divisors. But it is quietly ignored in this code as we get `!NaN*0`, which is \$0\$.

Answer (score 5):

## [Wolfram Language (Mathematica)](https://www.wolfram.com/wolframscript/), 25 bytes

```
--+#/(Tr@Divisors@#-#-1)&
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##JY3BSsRgDIRfRSjIqin9k/xJk4PQgw@g4AsUWdYedoVu3Yv47HV@PE2SmXxznrfP43nelo95Pz3vff/UDYf3dXpZbsv1a71OXd/1/HC/v67LZbsbprfv5bhNj6dh@nESJgnSwqRiVNPJcyRWVeIsSVIqEthJE6FgpLl4wnbjFrKGqA5T8DoSrpjT1ZnaaAhZBjDsKrB4dPcGrTIqiRVthNECJYI/JLU4ByTS0FTDA@CaZpJkVSqKo0S0hlJw@FevCbUG@t33Pw)

-1 byte from @att

Comment: [25 bytes](https://tio.run/##y00syUjNTSzJTE78n277X1dXW1lfI6TIwSWzLLM4v6jYQVlXWddQU@1/QFFmXomCQ3q0oYGpqYWxcez//wA)

Answer (score 5):

## [Haskell](https://www.haskell.org/), 38 bytes

```hs
k n=div n$sum[d|d<-[2..n-1],mod n d<1]
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##VZDBboMwDIbvfYocetikFsV2YmKJ7gn2BlUPSKANtUDVdttl784MJB1wiT7s/P6cz/J@ri@XYTib7lA136bb3r/aY/VbFfsjZlm3h9Ou7SvTmaqA09CWjfb1G2OOza4/Ffu2vJpbXVbZT3@r7sX27aN@vDddrR3XW9M9ti9n0xwO/U7bX/XnGDCY6eP5MLCZDoTIGDms6mRTnWdGH5kmdrLOY8kjTnlARJHDxGJlyWgdLPsRUv/sQ5Lmkx05wMoPLEvKn5g90MIXxK/2Q8cpj8c8VN3o60YfvZ3qIMrCxDMD6f2x6mnBXsLTX/OACeN9kLGeM/NiPoLDPPqR@qK3FP2AdT7mPsT9wY6s81M@6z5kGUJ6D68cxMf90Wu@CxzSPrned@I9yr@vd@ji@5BTDjaE6EeaD9ZqR2SxE7OTpx9Y//QjF/4A)

Answer (score 5):

## [Japt](https://github.com/ETHproductions/japt), <s>12</s> 6 [bytes](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ISO/IEC_8859-1)

```
zUâ ¤x
```

[Try it](https://petershaggynoble.github.io/Japt-Interpreter/?v=1.4.6&code=elXiIKR4&input=WzYsMjEsMjgsMzAxLDMyNSw0OTYsNjk3LDEzMzMsMTkwOSwyMDQxLDIxMzMsMzkwMSw4MTI4LDEwNjkzLDE2NTEzLDE5NTIxLDI0NjAxLDI2OTc3LDUxMzAxLDk2MzYxLDEzMDE1MywxNTk4NDEsMTYzMjAxLDE3NjY2MSwyMTQyNzMsMjUwMzIxLDI3NTgzMywyOTYzNDEsMzA2MTgxLDM4OTU5Myw0ODY4NzcsNDk1NTI5LDU0MjQxMyw4MDg4NjEsMTAwNTQyMSwxMDA1NjQ5LDEwNTU4MzNdLW0K)

- Uses [Jelly answer](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/223678/84844) formula

Comment: I believe this is the first time I've seen the pairing of values returned by `N.â()` that was introduced in v1.4.6 actually be useful. Nice one!

Comment: Yeah! Thanks @Shaggy ! I was wondering why not ordered ? when I realized how useful in that case !

Answer (score 5):

## [V (vim)](https://github.com/DJMcMayhem/V), <sup><s>81 79</s></sup> 70 bytes

```
"aD@ai0
<esc>V{g<c-a>{dd}dkqqC<c-r>=!(<c-r>a%<c-r>")*<c-r>"
<esc>k@qq@q:%s/\n/+
$x0C<c-r>=<c-r>a/(<c-r>")
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##K/v/XynRxSEx04DLJrU42S6sOt0mWTfRrjolpTYlu7DQGcgrsrNV1ADTiapgSklTC0JD9GQ7FBY6FFqpFuvH5Olrc6lUGEB1QfToa0A1cf3/b2T4X7cMAA)

Uses the observation in [rak1507's Jelly answer.](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/223678/80214)

-2 bytes from kops.

-9 more bytes from kops, removing the entire third line!

Comment: I haven't tried to figure out what this is doing but, as you guessed, the `dd` in the first line can be removed. It's a no-op since you can't remove a line from an empty file.

Comment: [A bit more golfing](https://tio.run/##K/v/XynRxSEx04DLJrU42S6sOt0mWTfRrjolpTYlu7DQGcgrsrNV1ADTiapgSklTC0JD9GQ7FBY6FFqpFuvH5Olrc6lUGEB1QfToa0A1cf3/b2T4X7cMAA) -- I think the third line of commands i mostly unnecessary by just throwing `*<c-r>"` into the first formula. Nice solution; I didn't know about visual mode g<c-a>!

Comment: I found `Vg<c-a>` while snooping around in the [LoTM thread.](https://codegolf.meta.stackexchange.com/a/21956/80214) Thanks for the help!

Answer (score 4):

## [05AB1E](https://github.com/Adriandmen/05AB1E), 5 bytes

*Ties [rak1507's Jelly answer](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/223678/94066) for #1.*

```
Ñ¨O<÷
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##yy9OTMpM/f//8MRDK/xtDm///9/QwMDUxMgQAA)

```
Ñ¨O<÷  # full program
       # implicit input...
    ÷  # divided by...
  O    # sum of...
Ñ      # divisors of...
       # implicit input...
 ¨     # excluding the last...
    ÷  # rounded down
       # implicit output
```

Answer (score 4):

## [C (gcc)](https://gcc.gnu.org/), <s>45</s> 44 bytes

```c
i,t;k(x){for(t=i=1;++t<x;)i-=x%t?0:t;x/=-i;}
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##ZVPBbqMwEL3zFbNZVSKqs7UxdnBT2tOeV8p5L2wwwQrBlTFpqqrfnh1skq60IIt59sx7b0Zmt9rvdpeLIX5zSM/Lj8a61JemZJv7e/903izNqjzf@Rf66Dfnh3JlNp@X76bfdWOt4WnwtbE/2uckadKeuOVHAqb3YEs4BLxJ4NXhTpMuDinc1QQXLKF8nr4PD3A3/O4XBDOJJbYs3cvCHhaPi5/b7a8tfJveBXJ8JhPpsTJ9uoQPlJKE4XaTZoxkMSjmHU4ZkTHKBOEhytU1X6o1YbGCcc4JK2KsqLrGGc3ZNSfDpFmAKyTmNMQFu8kxKhXSzEAKxmd1psSXuVxOrmJxhh7WJI9imI8nTAWgJJcI@NUfZYJ/QaGKyRidlXgWCufDtZTypsbybM0JnyckKEcjTM7drUUx9U1niJrIKueJUckK7FJEVCiBvWUi0uaFLND4uphHKkSmbu5EnuXYOs8jLGhRoB8@8zJKMQGxojcsc3UzxagIrniYyucFVmCg6mvwMA4aPxb22kNtTmawboBhPCZPr04/J/9dVix90zD4yuElHB101r7Cm/Et@JIFTo3rj8ZCDeeJWZ/jVfatPkLj7DHo1Bp1kn@uPsQn0BuvXeU1VF0Hp6ob9RCYqzpYNdDrfeXNSXfvYBo42nrsLPZiBqBJ/IXg61lBY3pkep@Ynfaj68E7O@5b0BU6dGZ3QKfRFFp/hxX2D2@t2bWxUdwNvhkMdiJpq1NoB@4ZoNPjZCxO8ZBi6fIv)

- uses [Jelly's](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/223678/84844) formula
- saved 1 by sum negatively and starting from 1

Explanation

```
   i and t used to get divisors sum
   for(t=i=1;++t<x;) - we start our loop with t=1 and end before x to exclude them from dividers 
   i-=x%t?0:t;       - we iterate all values and add to i negatively if modulo t is 0
   x/=-i;           - finally we return trough eax trick x divided by -sum which started from 1 so we have the +1 term added to k(sum)
```

Comment: Can you explain a little bit about what this code does? I'm very intrigued by it. Especially, I don't see any type declaration or return statement anywhere. In the Try it online you posted `k()` is also called with 2 arguments even though it was only defined with 1 argument.

Comment: @Jerie Wang forget about the k calls with 2 arguments.. Just a type error.. It works only because it ignores the second argument. For type declarations C defaults global variables and function parameters to int (it just live a warning) . The missing return is a famous trick in C: it uses eax register, note the final assignment to x , this is equivalent to the return statement [some explanation here](https://stackoverflow.com/q/32513793/7699953) . I'll add explanation soon in the answer

Answer (score 4):

## [R](https://www.r-project.org/), 35 bytes

```r
function(x,y=x-1)y/sum(2:y*!x%%2:y)
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##K/qfHZ9RWZBaBERpqckltv/TSvOSSzLz8zQqdCptK3QNNSv1i0tzNYysKrUUK1RVgbQmmh4NM00uNBEjQ0whCwwhQwMzS2MsoqamFsbGmv8B)

Inspired by [@Dominic's answer to linked challenge](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/211058/55372).

Uses the fact that \$\sigma(n)-n-1\$ for `n>2` is just sum of divisors that lie between `2` and `n-1`.  Then, we simply divide `n-1` by the obtained value to get `k` (as `n` is guaranteed to be hyperperfect).

#### [R](https://www.r-project.org/), 34 bytes

```r
function(x)x%/%sum(2:x*!x%%2:x,-x)
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##K/qfHZ9RWZBaBERpqckltv/TSvOSSzLz8zQqNCtU9VWLS3M1jKwqtBQrVFWBtI5uhSaaFg0zTS40ESNDTCELDCFDAzNLYyyipqYWxsaa/wE)

Using [@rak's formula](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/223678/55372).

Answer (score 3):

## [Retina 0.8.2](https://github.com/m-ender/retina/wiki/The-Language/a950ad7d925ec9316e3e2fb2cf5d49fd15d23e3d), 54 bytes

```
.+
$*
1(?=(1(?<=(?=(?(\3+$)(\2?\3)))(1+)))+1)(\2)+
$#4
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##Vc69DgIhDADgnae4xDMpkhjaIkLihdGXYNDBwcXB3Psjv/GOoeWjTen3tb4/z3SE@yOdlZhPAiEskMNtKZcAkdUsIVKILKUEVDkqLC8y9x9MSlM9tqUJRU2E3dTtdnXWo26b6dLN1cbv51l/7azzkJm7XbXXfmvSBrf9hKO/7cN@/M@62OF/vx8) Link includes faster test cases. Explanation:

```
.+
$*
```

Convert the input to unary.

```
1(?=(1(?<=(?=(?(\3+$)(\2?\3)))(1+)))+1)(\2)+
$#4
```

Based on @Deadcode's answer to [Am I not good enough for you?](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/181350) this calculates the sum of divisors from `2` to `n-1`, but golfed down (removed a `^` and two `$`s) by assuming that the input is a hyperperfect number. After the sum of divisors is calculated the result is then divided into `n-1`.

Answer (score 2):

## [Python 3](https://docs.python.org/3/), <s>46</s> 45 bytes

1 byte off thanks to [@dingledooper](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/users/88546/dingledooper)! Also, this uses the floor trick from [@rak1507's answer](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/223678/36398).

```python
lambda n:n//sum(k*(n%k<1)for k in range(2,n))
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##JY/BTsQwDETvfEUvSC2ytLEdu/EKvgQ4FEFh1d3sqpQDX18m4mRnZvxGuf1uX9eq@/z0sp@ny9v71NVjPRy@fy798tDX@@WRh/m6dkt3qt061c@PXqgOw97ErYnPTsIkhTQxqRjlcPIYiVWVOFKQpIwE3qSBUGGkOXnAduMWsobIDlNwOhJU7OHqTG01hCwKMOwqsHh09wbNMiqJJW2E0QpKBHdIanIuGCUMTbl4ATiHmQRZlozikkppDSlB@J@eA9Ma6PV4193WU936ud/w5T8)

Comment: [45 bytes](https://tio.run/##JY/BTsQwDETvfEUvSC2ytLEdu/EKvgQ4FEFh1d3sqpQDX18m4mRnZvxGuf1uX9eq@/z0sp@ny9v71NVjPRy@fy798tDX@@WRh/m6dkt3qt061c@PXqgOw97ErYnPTsIkhTQxqRjlcPIYiVWVOFKQpIwE3qSBUGGkOXnAduMWsobIDlNwOhJU7OHqTG01hCwKMOwqsHh09wbNMiqJJW2E0QpKBHdIanIuGCUMTbl4ATiHmQRZlozikkppDSlB@J@eA9Ma6PV4193WU936ud/w5T8)

Comment: @dingledooper Thank you! I had `lambda n:n//sum(k for k in range(2,n)if n%k<1)` but it was still `46` bytes

Comment: @LuisMendo you haven't updated the code

Comment: @rak1507 Updated now, thanks!

Comment: That would be one byte shorter in Python 2 (using `/` instead of `//`).

Answer (score 2):

## [K (oK)](https://github.com/JohnEarnest/ok), 18 bytes

```
{_x%+/1_&~(!x)!'x}
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##JY07DgJBDEOvEgpYEELkPwmXoaOhoF0JwdUXj6icxM7z8/J6btvj9r6v@/NV7ofvcbeedsv62R4LJamQFhkLmQZ5J2UPEjMjaW5SdiSwkzVCJUgLZ8POkBmKifCEqXgdhCvmTkuhOQZC0QWMpCksGZk5oa7DSINtEkYUShR/SBqnFKQ60OSVBbB3hDaFq6O4uGo2MOPw1/SGxgRtPw)

A port of @Jonah's [J answer](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/223680/75681) - don't forget to upvote him!

Answer (score 1):

## [Vyxal](https://github.com/Lyxal/Vyxal), 4 bytes

```
∆K‹ḭ
```

[Try it Online!](http://lyxal.pythonanywhere.com?flags=&code=%E2%88%86K%E2%80%B9%E1%B8%AD&inputs=697&header=&footer=)

Porting the jelly answer ftw

### Explained

```
∆K‹ḭ
∆K   # sum of proper divisors of input
  ‹  # ↑ - 1
   ḭ # input // ↑ (integer division)
```

Comment: why??? why is `∆K` a thing??

Comment: @Makonede because jelly has it too

Comment: Oh that took me a second... I thought that it took \$3\$ bytes (like in 05AB1E) because I forgot that `$` was a quick to combine links into a monad

Answer (score 1):

## Excel, 52 bytes

```
=LET(n,A2-1,q,SEQUENCE(n),n/SUM((MOD(A2,q)=0)*q,-1))
```

Works except for the last test case. `SEQUENCE` is limited to 2^20.  The following works up to 2^40 and is 79 bytes.

```
=LET(q,SEQUENCE(A2^0.5),a,(MOD(A2,q)=0)*q,(A2-1)/(SUM(a,IFERROR(A2/a,0))-A2-1))
```

Answer (score 1):

## [Pari/GP](https://pari.math.u-bordeaux.fr/gp.html), 23 bytes

```
n\sum(i=2,n-1,!(n%i)*i)
```